# Why can't I use my SO account to comment on the SO blog?

Tags: feature-request, blog

I tried to comment on [a post in the SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/What-Programming-Languages-Weekends/) and I could not use my SO credentials - only Discus/FB/Twitter/Google.

It would be nice if the default were the SO credentials - or at least they were available.

Comment: *"Twitter/Goodle"* I read that as "Twiddle"

Comment: It used to be possible [somewhat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141906/log-in-to-disqus-with-stackexchange-openid) as Disqus did support OpenId and SE offers an OpenID service. But it was flaky back then and today I no longer see an OpenId option for Disqus.

Comment: here is a more recent dupe on MSE : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288641/why-cant-i-comment-on-the-stack-overflow-blog-even-though-i-am-signed-in-to-sta

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The blog is not in any way integrated into the normal Q&A sites. We dabbled with some limited integration back when we ran it on WordPress, but those days are long gone. Instead, we use [Disqus](http://disqus.com), a third-party comment-hosting service, just in case anyone wanders by and cannot resist typing words.

If it's ever critical (or even mildly interesting) to have folks' responses to a blog post associated with their account on Stack Overflow, we'll just post it on meta here instead. Of course, if you see something on the blog that you'd like to discuss in depth here, you can *always* bring it up yourself.

Comment: `... we'll just post it on meta here instead.` FAMOUS LAST WORDS

Comment: Considering that SO and Discus more or less support the same providers (there are some glaring exceptions in some sites, Launchpad for example), you might use the same account for both SO and Discus.

Comment: As rene mentioned in the comments here, Disqus does *not* appear to support OpenID, @Braiam - which excludes 3rd-party services like Launchpad and also Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider.