# Pair blog announcements with meta questions

Tags: discussion, blog

Today there was another announcement in the blog:
[Why Channels?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/11/09/why-channels/?cb=1)

I like the blog posts well enough, no problem there. However, I do not really feel like creating an account in order to leave a comment on the blog page. In my opinion, it would just make more sense if the comments for the blog were simply the same structure as Stack Overflow comments are anyway, but that is a topic for another time.

Given that the current comment structure on the blog prevents Stack Overflow users, or Stack Exchange users, from comment, I think **it would make sense if blog posts were also paired with meta Stack Overflow discussion posts** so that the community can have a place to discuss, comment, and interact (vote) on the current topic being announced or raised in the blog.

Comment: In this particular instance, most of the discussion/questions for channels will likely fit in the "What's Happening With Channels" post. However, it should be paired as in linked to the blog, too, so it's easy enough to find there.

Comment: @Kendra - I don't think there needs to really be an evergreen post to pair with all blog posts for each topic. Maybe the post tumbleweeds, maybe not. It doesn't need to be a massive endeavor, just somewhere to post a little bit of feedback on the blog post and its contents.

Comment: @Rob - I acknowledge that the blog comment structure is highly unlikely to change. Which is why I proposing that in addition to creating a blog post, there should be a meta Stack Overflow post which accompanies these in order to be more inclusive to the community here.

Comment: @TravisJ Very sorry - I misread the last part of your proposal.

Comment: You know what actually bothers me: that it fills up two spots on the Community Bulletin. It reduces by half the spots available for hot meta posts (and if there are many featured items there would be none).

Comment: @Braiam noted! This was recently brought to my attention, and we've started to choose 1: either meta or the blog. So hopefully you won't have a clogged feed as often.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the feedback, Travis!

If you don't want to use the blog commenting system, feel free to move the discussion over to Meta in a new thread.

Comment: The blog commenting system prevents a vast amount of Stack Overflow users from commenting, not just me. The reasoning is that if there is anything worth discussing, users can raise their issue on meta. That is [by design, as Josh notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343326/). Moreover, commenting on the blog still does not allow us to vote.

Comment: My point with this meta post here was that not pairing the blog with a meta post leaves out a lot of input from the community. While the current design does allow meta to create discussions about nuances, tangents, and related topics to the blog, it often misses the bigger picture being presented. The fragmentation caused lacks the strong guidance that a sponsored discussion about the *entire* blog post would have, as well as creating a disconnect between community and outreach.