# Are blog comments disabled or buggy?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-experience, blog

I read the latest blog post and wanted to ask for clarification on one point, so I scrolled down to the comments section and found this:

[image: Screenshot of "Comments" header, empty space, recent tweets]

I opened up the developer console of my browser to see whether there were any JavaScript errors, but no. I tried a couple of other browsers, but the bug seemed to be reproduced. So I headed over to meta.stackoverflow.com and discovered [an answer which states that comments are disabled on the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366690/573420).

**If the comments are disabled, why is there a header for the comments section and no message saying "Comments on this post are disabled"?** Basic UX demands that either the header is removed or a message is added, especially given that expectations are conditioned by the fact that many sites *do* now load comments after the main page using JavaScript.

Comment: Not surprised. The blog theme feels like an afterthought overall IMO.

Comment: Comments were left off of that specific post for fear of an uprising by us - the community.

Comment: @JonH, there have already been at least two similar comments deleted. The question is **not** "*Why were comments disabled?*" The question is why the *fact* that comments were disabled was not clear on the page itself.

Comment: I know I agree its a pretty buggy system. Ive asked the same question in the past.

Comment: A bit ironic considering the poster of the blog post is head of user experience...

Comment: @JonH: I guess he forgot that if you find you have to pre-emptively block responses because you already know everybody vehemently disagrees with you, perhaps the story you're telling is not the right story.

Comment: @JonH, when you say that you've asked the same question in the past, do you mean that you've wondered it, or that you've posted it in meta? I don't see it in a search through your questions, but if this is a dupe then by all means vote to close it as such.

Comment: Ive asked it before on meta about why some blog posts have comments and why others dont even though it says comment. Ill have to search for it but I remember asking at least something similiar. Maybe I commented.

Comment: Irony: a blog post stating "Stack Overflow isn't very welcome" is not welcoming comments.... The pot calling the kettle black?

Comment: By the way, you could also comment to his tweet....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've confirmed with our dev/design team that this should be fixed now. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.