# How can we as a community put more of an emphasis on learning?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

There has been a lot of talk recently about how we treat new users, prompted by [a certain blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). A lot of this discussion has centered around a [false dichotomy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness) of experienced users who care about quality and new users who clutter up Stack Overflow with dupes and bad questions. Ideally, older users don't *only* care about the quality of answers on the site, and newer users don't *only* care about getting the answer to their question; they both care about learning and helping each other.

I came across the meta post *[Should I be discouraged by Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/should-i-be-discouraged-by-stack-overflow)* earlier, and the answers are all overwhelmingly positive and welcoming. They stress that Stack Exchange is a community for learning, and that you're not going to be a pro when you first start out. But many of them also talk about feeling discouraged when they first started on the site as well. How do we combat this?

Honestly, our current system of upvotes and downvotes and closevotes and dupehammers doesn't seem like one that stresses the fact that all of us (with the possible exception of Jon Skeet) are learning and helping one another learn; nor does the site language that constantly stresses that this is a place for 'professionals' and 'experts' (as though professionals and experts in a field don't get that way by constantly learning).

So many people learn programming on their own without any kind of formal training, and honestly, that's fantastic. I believe Stack Overflow could be a great tool to supplement this kind of learning, no matter what level you happen to be at, but it's not there yet. How do we get there?

Comment: We are there?  There is that free-to-use massive database of Q&A.

Comment: This speaks to a misconception (or corruption) of the goal of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Makoto I was afraid of that:(   We cannot teach 'Computers 101', and should not try.

Comment: @MartinJames:  It's easy to see how this misconception could form.  I learn stuff from Stack Overflow every day (and I'm sure Jon Skeet does too).  That doesn't *immediately* make Stack Overflow a learning platform.

Comment: I learn a lot too, but I certainly have no teaching qualifications, (or skills, probably:).

Comment: There are things.  Someone, (@bro?)., has a user script that can filter question on poster rep.  Intended to filter out new account questions from <10 rep, it could filter in questions with, say <100 rep.  That may present a better match of Q&A to skill-level for minimally skilled students.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feedback on the blog post: Is this the actual mission and goal of Stack Overflow now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387385/feedback-on-the-blog-post-is-this-the-actual-mission-and-goal-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: see also: [Codifying the Scope: Differentiate between Teaching and Helping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370486/839601)

Answer (score 26):

That [meta post you refer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/should-i-be-discouraged-by-stack-overflow) overlooks one specific, but extremely important category of questions, and that is those questions from askers that expect the Stack Overflow community to *provide one-on-one mentoring.*

Stack Overflow is simply not set up for this.  I would suggest that, if you earnestly want to learn how to become a software developer, asking questions one at a time on Stack Overflow is *the hardest possible way to do that.*

The reasons for this should be obvious.  Without a fundamental grounding in the basics, how are you ever going to formulate a coherent question or understand any answer we provide you?

> **ME:** Click the right mouse button.
> **NOOB:** What's a mouse?

This is going to be a very difficult idea for some people to accept, but here goes:

#### You have to earn the right to ask questions of experts

How do you earn that right?  By doing your homework.  By searching for answers first.  By attempting to solve the problem yourself first.  By doing these things, you gain insight and context into the problem, which will help you formulate your question.  And then, when you do ask, by stating your problem clearly and succinctly using proper grammar and spelling, while providing the necessary information for the expert to solve it.

There's nothing wrong with being a beginner.  Everybody starts there.  What I'm saying is that you probably need to have progressed beyond the beginner stage, even if it's just a single book or class in Java programming, for Stack Overflow to be a useful tool for you.

**Further Reading**
[Asking Good Questions is Hard (But Worth It)](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/08/31/asking-questions/)

Comment: a possible related feature request is to requre a user to both create an account and spend {x} minutes reading {y} different questions on the site before they can ask a question. This can easily be measured in JavaScript, for example in Discourse we've always measured exactly how long every post is read by every user in the system, because we believe reading is fundamental.

Comment: @JeffAtwood that, and Z minutes taking the tour.

Comment: @MartinJames and the badge should be linked to that. Even just making the tour paginated with a click through after each section would prevent just scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: `if you earnestly want to learn how to become a software developer` you should be able to Google the heck out of it...

Comment: @brasofilo: Learning how to program via Google is the *second* hardest way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

We have enough of an emphasis on learning already. We are all about learning. We are here because we don't know things and want to learn, or because we know things and want other people to learn, or because both reasons. Active users spend a very large amount of time looking for new opportunities to help people learn.

We are not here to engage in *every possible mode of learning*. We are not here to provide personalized tutoring. We are not here to be a substitute for Google. We are not here to explain the entire task of recognizing product logos in an image, or of building Facebook, or of [insert entire 5-part homework assignment].

We don't need more emphasis on learning. We may need more emphasis on *how* we help people learn, but not on learning itself.

Comment: The deal-breaker is 'who wants to volunteer to mark the homework?'