# Codifying the Scope: Differentiate between Teaching and Helping on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope, welcoming

I'd like to see the loop closed on what we need to do with the site's cultural perception of "niceness", and eliminate any ambiguity.  While I understand that there are some things which will be codified as part of our Code of Conduct, I'd like to see if we can head it off even further.

Note that this is definitely not a dupe of [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/1079354).  *That* question wishes to bring back a horribly abused close reason to "help" deal with this.  What I'm proposing instead is a cultural revolution.

---

I wanted to take a moment to figure out what the "problem" was after the now-infamous [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) went up, and to see what could be done about it, but every time I thought about it, [and even after I was lambasted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367562/1079354) for meekly proposing a solution to what I *thought* was the problem, I realized that there's...not really a "problem" per se.

The main issue with Stack Overflow is one of a complete misunderstanding as to what Stack Overflow's purpose is within the world.  This misunderstanding is present on both sides, from low and high rep users alike.

### Stack Overflow is used as a place to *learn*.

Honestly, this is fine at face value; upon reading new and insightful information, you have gained new knowledge (i.e. *have learned something*) and are now better for it.  This is fantastic!  Experts are sharing their knowledge, and non-experts alike are getting more and more confidence in what they have to do on a daily basis.

However..."learning" is a double-edged sword.  Remember...

### Stack Overflow is used as a place to *learn*.

This can mean that a user *learns* stuff while they're here and can also mean that they have an expectation of experts to **teach** them.

So in this, we have a problem:  users are using Stack Overflow to learn, which by extension, means that they ask questions which are blatantly questions which would require us to teach them on how to use a technology or concept.

> I want to write a Java batch program to execute this DB script and pass those records into method in batch of 500. Kindly help in this with code snippet.

> Anybody had problems running an app implementing firebase database, as in the app just crashes at startup

> Can I create an Arraylist like `ArrayList<Integer, Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();` in Java ?
>
> What I actually require is store a pair at each element of an ArrayList and sort in non-decreasing order based on the first element of each pair.

---

The best questions we have on our site are questions which are looking for *help*.  That is, they're looking to solve a particular and specific problem and don't require us to author miniature lectures on the subject.   The best *answers* we have on this site are the ones who concisely illustrate the problem and solution.

Therefore, I propose that we *carefully* define what it is we mean when we state that we're here to "help", specifically in the FAQ.  I'm no wordsmith—I failed for about 3 days attempting to come up with something here—but something along the lines of the below would be enough in my eyes.

> ### Asking for Help
>
> Automatically, when you ask a question on Stack Overflow, we assume
>   that you're asking for some kind of help with a problem, which is fine
>   - we're happy to help you out.  However, questions which ask the community to fundamentally teach you a new concept are frowned upon,
>   simply because it takes a lot of energy—on both sides—to be sure
>   that the concept is properly communicated.
>
> Some examples of teaching questions include:
>
> - How do I implement FooWidget in Android?
> - I want to write this application which foos the bar and creates baz at specific times of day.  Can anyone help me do it?
> - When and why would I use Quux technology and how would I test it?

Comment: You've been using this story for a while in your meta posts.  I've been detesting it for about as long.  A very basic problem is that it assumes that questions are for questioners.  Which is nonsensical, there is only ever *one* of them.  The other, oh, two dozen or more are there to actually learn something new.  Question, shmestion, it is the answer from a skilled SO contributor that is actually interesting.

Comment: @HansPassant:  Of *course* that's the only interesting thing.  The problem that everyone has right now is the fact that the boring bit is so *bad*.  You've seen them before. Questions which just ask us to teach them a thing.  Do we *really* want experts exerting their energy on that?

Comment: Something else you've been doing, advocating for skilled SO contributors to *not* post an answer to a crappy question.  How the heck does that produce interesting content?  Of course it doesn't.

Comment: @HansPassant:  Hopefully it gets us away from what ultimately wound up killing Documentation:  lots of contributors taking the low-hanging fruit instead of addressing more complex questions.  There are a billion resources out there on how to instantiate an array or how to solve the "Roman Numerals" problem.  There are a lot fewer answers on meaningful differences between annotation and XML-based Spring wiring (or at least, there *were* until about 8 months ago).  There are good and interesting questions out there.  They're buried by the noise of bad questions.

Comment: You are veering off to the left.  Docs failure has plenty of good explanations that don't have anything to do with learning or Q+A.  Minimalism would be a good trait for Docs, exceptionalism a bad one, the exact opposite of what is good for Q+A.

Comment: The art of filling the knowledge gap. Any expert forum will eventually house teachers eager to teach. Sometimes bad questions provide that opportunity. And yes there are a LOT of silly OP's but when I click on a tag of interest the list is reduced to topics that interest me. I don't read everything. Some platforms I need to google before I understand what the question is about.

Comment: @HansPassant I eagerly await the "interesting content" you produce by answering all of the crappy questions.

Comment: I think your proposed help section wording is insufficiently clear to a new user who isn't fluent in English on whether the proposed questions are meant to be good or bad examples.

Comment: You need to step a long way back from SO and look at it from the point of view of a revenue-generating casual visitor. This distinction is too specialised for them. Btw @HansPassant your answers have introduced me to several concepts that I'd never heard of before.  They are shining examples of how good SO can be at teaching (people who want to learn).

Comment: @SList I would appreciate if you abstain of pretending to talk for all such visitors. I am such a visitor myself and to me the distinction is clear and important. When I do coding and bump into problem I type my issue into google box and get the solution I need, most often it is from SO. When I am looking to learn something I also type into search box to find things I need but frequently popping links from SO in this case tend to be useless trash compared to real, normal tutorials

Comment: ...when I learn something the only useful thing at SO is to figure the right tag and check its wiki, sometimes these make a great starting point. Although I don't recall tag wiki popping in search results

Comment: There is a dichotomy. On the one hand, SO professes to be a Q&A serving far more users than the question asker. On the other, the interface and interaction we see on a daily basis seems geared towards helping a single user. The big green tick doesn't *need* to pin an answer to the top, we shouldn't *need* 10+ comments to have a question clarified (and they shouldn't claim so much screen real estate), I've seen the +15 encourage bad practice in tags where the answerer has breached the rep cap (get rewarded for fixing user's problem, no benefit from helping the Q&A by explaining your solution)..

Comment: ..So my point is that there need to be interface & reward-based changes to accompany any change in advice. Advice is great, but we all know that it's not always, or rarely, followed. UI focus and incentives need to change first.

Comment: @jpp Honestly, there is a huge cultural difference between tags. The phenomenon you said is very unlikely to happen in tag like C++, where too-localized beginner questions will be heavily downvoted and closed very quickly. For me, the dichotomy is the long term usefulness and the popularity among *current regular participants* ( not the questioner ). Unfortunately, usefulness and popularity don't align very well.

Comment: @gnat, you've been a member for 6 years and have answered 103 questions.  You also comment on Meta.  In no way are you a casual, revenue-generating user, by which I mean users that don't even bother to make a profile, and see advertisements.  I won't repeat your own words back to you, because they are not very nice.

Comment: I see it like this: its basically street food VS fine dining in restaurants. People often come to Stack Overflow looking to get a three course meal, but all we serve is street food. Bite-sized learning and teaching. You can argue with the staff all you want, you need to go to the proper venue to get the service you desire.

Comment: @SList when it comes to looking for coding help I turn exactly into that casual visitor, probably no different from many (most) others. When it comes to this it becomes irrelevant that I can answer about stuff I know and that I am also curious about how site works which made me active at meta. When I need help with coding I need help just like anyone else, I would be looking for it exactly the same if I had no profile, no answers, no meta activity (the only difference from most is maybe that I know and use a trick with tag wikis but it doesn't matter much)

Comment: I don't think we will ever 'close the loop' on niceness so long as people keep putting that and similar terms in "scare quotes"

Comment: Your text following "Some examples of teaching questions include:" is **not** very useful to beginner programmers. Sure, most experienced coders have encountered the terms "foo", "bar", "baz", and possibly "quux", but to a newbie that's just a bunch of gobbledygook.

Comment: I enjoy StackOverflow because I can teach and learn. I do not enjoy being used as a cheap help desk. This is absolutely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 40):

I cautiously disagree with the premise of this post.

For one thing, I'm not sure whether I naturally interpret "teach you a new concept" in the same way as you, and if not then we'll be talking at cross-purposes, at least somewhat. I'm not sure how to easily test this empirically, but I fear that it's exactly the sort of imprecise phrase that different people will read, nod at, and decide they understand, all without realising that they understood it in profoundly different ways.

Secondly, loads of the site's [top 50 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) look to me like "teach me this concept" questions. Namely, these ones:

- [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
- [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)
- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)
- [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)
- [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)
- [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Looking at the top 50 questions is my standard first-line technique for assessing whether a proposed rule about what makes a good question is actually true. In this case, as usual, I find that the top 50 questions contain loads of examples that violate the rule, which suggests that the rule is fundamentally flawed.

In general, nailing down in words some universal criteria for what makes a good question is *really hard*. I don't think you've succeeded at it here, and I think that publishing guidance that is not universally true is a bad move that will just lead to good questions getting unfairly criticised and closed. If a piece of guidance about asking a good question doesn't pass the test of being something that the site's top 50 questions follow, then I don't think it should exist.

Comment: Isn't the main point that most "teach me a concept" questions have been done? The ones we get nowadays should be marked as duplicates of the canonicals. *If this is the case*, the solution to the problem can't just be updating guidance (which few read), it should require making it easier to close duplicates before they cost the community time/effort or knowledge dilution by FGITW answers.

Comment: @jpp *'Isn't the main point that most "teach me a concept" questions have been done?'* - that's not a point I see made anywhere in Makoto's post; you're the first person here to mention duplicates. To what extent the point is true, I'm honestly unsure; you may be right.

Comment: I agree with this answer. From the question: `The best questions we have on our site are questions which are looking for help. That is, they're looking to solve a particular and specific problem and don't require us to author miniature lectures on the subject. The best answers we have on this site are the ones who concisely illustrate the problem and solution.` this claim is totally false, as you've demonstrated. The site has always rewarded more extensive *teaching* answers **way** more than simple/minimal *helping* answers.

Comment: You need to be careful with the examples you're using to defend this position.  **All of the questions you reference are from 2008-2009.**  None of them could be asked on today's Stack Overflow, so it's completely unfair to say that these are examples which violate the "rule" when we didn't have question quality standards back then.  Questions which are old have been treated more like museum pieces rather than exemplars of high quality questions, and while they're useful, those aren't the kinds of questions we actively permit users to ask today.

Comment: @TylerH:  I should be explicit - if someone asks on Stack Overflow for them to show you how a framework works, that would be something I consider to be a "teaching" question.  If someone asks you how you they can fix a thing with their framework, that's a question I would *not* consider to be a teaching question.  With that in mind, can you find an example as recent as 2013 which illustrates a teaching question which *isn't* closed?

Comment: @Makoto Uh... I think you see the site through a totally different lens than the rest of us; *almost all* of the top 50 questions that Mark references would be fine to ask today... maybe 5 would not.

Comment: @Makoto As for "teaching" - yes, my two highest scoring answers, for starters. It's quite easy, just take your pick from the first **340 pages** of search results at https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Newest&q=is%3aa%20score%3a100..%20closed%3ano for [Great Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) as recent as 2013. Many of them will naturally be answers that teach as much as or moreso than 'help' by your overly narrow definition of it.

Comment: And if you don't want to put in the effort to search for them yourself, [here's one from June 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819413/why-are-types-always-a-certain-size-no-matter-its-value)

Comment: @TylerH:  I really do want to be clear here.   I think the biggest premise of this post when I first drafted it (a couple of months ago) was that I was concerned that the CoC would suddenly shift and look to foster new comers to Stack Overflow who *didn't* want to put the time and effort into researching their questions and wanted us to do all of the leg work for them.  All of our moderation tools tell us that "this is a bad thing and we have a way to redress this", but there's nothing in our FAQ or policy that says that this is bad.

Comment: @TylerH:  "Teaching" questions - e.g. questions who ask about something which is not narrow at all and would require a lecture to explain - are still fairly common.  It so happens to be the case that you're still pulling out examples of questions which I don't see as "teaching" since they're still quite narrow in focus and in scope.  Questions which *aren't* narrow in scope or narrow in focus are still asked in droves, and to be blunt, no one seems to be that excited to do anything to stymie that tide.

Comment: @TylerH:  All that to say...I don't think I'm satisfied with your examples.  You're cherry-picking questions who have a narrow premise and believing them to be "teaching", when in reality someone could definitely *learn* from them but the OP is not asking too much of you.  This is the part that needs to be clearly defined and clearly dealt with.

Comment: @Makoto a lecture is typically 50 minutes to multiple hours - none of the answers being talked about here are anywhere near that long. Even the famous branch prediction failure answer takes less than 5 minutes to read. So accusing of these popular questions of 'requiring a lecture to explain' is simply wrong on your part. As for the rest, you can't ask me to "find some examples" and then accuse me of cherry picking; it's literally what you asked for. Anyway, I come from a long line of teachers, trust me when I say you've clearly been misinformed as to what constitutes teaching.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  I've had a better chance to peruse your answer, and interestingly enough I feel like you're getting my point.  I did intentionally use the overloaded phrase "teach" since it means so many different things to different people, and it is quite contentious at that.  However, I still want to caution you here; the top 50 questions on the site are old and while some *might* be good, we have to treat them more like museum pieces than examples of good questions to ask.

Comment: I accept that I don't do a very good job of defining a difference between "teach" and "learn" - it's hard - but that doesn't mean that such a difference doesn't inherently *exist*.  More or less, we can at least warrant putting information out there that says, "Hey, we're fine with answering your questions, regardless of what level they are, but it's unreasonable to demand that we teach you every facet of this technology you had a question about."

Answer (score 21):

It comes down to scope.

Some questions that implicitly or explicitly ask for a tutorial are simply too broad. It's clear that the OP doesn't have the basic knowledge that they need to solve their current problem. They need to read a good tutorial or reference page on the topic / language feature, or discuss it with their teacher. Without at least some solid foundation in the topic it's very difficult for us to help them on SO. It's hard for us to know which elements of the topic they already know, or what misunderstandings they have, so it's difficult for us to gauge the level of detail required in our answer. We don't have the time or space to write a whole book chapter. Nor can we enter into the kind of dialogue that proper tuition generally requires. OTOH, it *is* possible to have some tutorial dialogue in a chat room, but even that is often less than ideal.

However, with some questions it's pretty clear that the OP *does* have most of the required foundation knowledge, they just have a few gaps, and maybe a misunderstanding or two, and their question is reasonably well-focused. In that situation it's perfectly fine (IMHO) that the answer has a tutorial component that utilizes the question and answer as a worked example.

Some people can learn how to do things purely from abstract descriptions, but most of us find it a lot easier when we can see a practical demonstration. Of course, most language tutorials contain example code, but in many library references the examples are pretty sparse, but in either case seeing some code in action, accompanied by relevant explanation, can go a long way in helping a student to properly assimilate a new topic.

FWIW, many of my favourite SO answerers often have at least some tutorial component in their answers. In contrast, answers that consist of an opaque code dump with no explanation of what's going on are of limited appeal to me, and I suspect are of limited value to most readers (apart from the cargo-cult coders).

Comment: I agree, "too broad" basically covers what I understand the Question to be about.

Comment: @CindyMeister:  That deals with the problem after the fact.  What I'm proposing is something to deal with that *before* it becomes a problem we have to address en masse.

Comment: @Makoto But IMO a majority of the people who ask these kinds of questions won't understand the kind of text you propose because they simply lack the necessary technical background. I'm not sure it's possible to prevent it.

Comment: @CindyMeister:  Then I fear the damage may already have been done.

Answer (score 10):

I only agree with half of what you say, namely,

**casual users (the world) expect to be taught or given assistance on SO**

To be honest, the first time I first understood all those catch phrases thrown at new users:

> We vote on questions not people. 
>   Do you expect a comment on upvotes as well?
>   A good question is as important as a good answer, maybe more.

and some more, is when the most important one hit me properly:

> We are a community aimed at building a repository of high quality knowledge.

When I understood that properly, the dissonance with my expectations of SO was gone. I no longer felt bad about things I used to get upset about (interacting around here). It became clear to me that **this is not a teaching community, nor a learning community**, and that's the best advice I think we can give new users. **We collect high quality, moderated knowledge in the form of QA.** Not everyone can or should be expected to contribute. **Once you have the repository it is of course a learning resource, but no teaching (as a policy) is involved in the process of building it.**

I will admit, it did take a while to understand, and I did take some things personally that I shouldn't have, so this dissonance with expectations will likely remain without some heavy handed solutions already down voted on meta. It's hard to shake off the feeling a down vote gives you in a robotic manner, especially if you are unfamiliar with SO.

Comment: It's important to not lose sight of the fact that the way we get almost all the questions for our repository is by offering answers as a *quid pro quo*.  Questioners are looking for a solution to their problem right away, and this is where the mismatch enters.  Many questioners have different expectations of sites where they can get programming help than this community has, or wants to have.  The ones who get themselves in trouble and go away in a huff are generally those who don't pause to take the temperature of the room, and especially those who don't appreciate that temperatures differ.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree. It is hard to guess a-priori that posting a question on a QA site is, in fact, something that requires careful planning and work. When asking you are tasked with creating a helpful **question** - the questioner is the one doing the helping!. This is in contrast to, I think it's safe to say, all other QA sites.

Comment: *"When, I understood that properly, the dissonance with my expectations of SO was gone."* - yup, same here. Luckily I learned it early on with only very little reaction from the moderation side of things; couple of deleted comments here and there. Basically I discovered meta and started reading. And reading. And reading more.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation of the more orthodox position on SO that I've seen. Upvote for you. - However, unfortunately, current official policy doesn't quite fit with this few, or more accurately, current official policy is so broadly/confusingly stated that it allows interpretations contrary to this view. Let's see where this controversy takes us.

Comment: @Danegraphics don't know if that is specifically to do with the written policy, people do like to read what they want to read. And not read what they don't want to read. Especially the latter is kind of hard to deal with.

Answer (score 9):

## This isn't something we can fix, because your question is based on a faulty premise.

Namely, you seem to have an artificially-scoped (read: wrong) definition of 'teaching'. Your post insinuates that people who come here for help *don't* want to be taught, or specifically that helping them doesn't include teaching them.

You're drawing way too big of a distinction between the two terms, seemingly in order to create what amounts to a fake definition of teaching. All teaching is, first and foremost, a form of helping, just like all squares are a form of rectangle. However, when you help someone with a problem, you are in many ways teaching them as well, regardless of what the problem or setting may be. Okay, so maybe that's not what you mean, maybe you mean on a bigger scale. That's fine, because that doesn't change anything:

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teach):

> #### Definition of teach
>
> - to cause to know something
> - to guide the studies of
> - to impart the knowledge of
> - to instruct by precept, example

Teaching encompasses *everything*, from informing someone of a single fact or observation, to taking someone who knows nothing about programming and making them an industry-level programmer. Even closing a question is teaching, because it helps make someone aware either that there is a duplicate system they can take advantage of, or that they should look harder for typos next time, or it might teach them about the concept of debugging on your own by removing lines of code until you isolate and reproduce the error (at least 4 out of every 5 times I have a problem, this method lets me find the solution on my own).

Likewise, you don't have to ask about a broad concept to get an answer that teaches you something. I've had people respond to two- and three-line answers of mine before saying things like 'learn something knew every day' or 'thanks, I didn't know that'. *That's teaching*. A lesson does not have to be lengthy to be considered teaching. In short, every answer ever posted (and upvoted, essentially) has the potential to teach someone something.

### Okay, but what about, like, really, really broad or lengthy teaching questions?

We already have a way to handle that. The "Too Broad" close reason exists, and both the Help Center and the Tour talk about how questions should be reasonably-scoped and as specific as possible, and that "if you can imagine a book on the subject of your question, you're probably asking a poor question for Stack Overflow" (I'm paraphrasing here).

Even so, though, there's nothing in the Stack Overflow rule book that says teaching someone concepts is *verboten* here. As a matter of fact, the subheading of the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page says:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every question about programming**.

(emphasis mine)

Broader conceptual questions about programming definitely fall under the umbrella of "every question about programming", and read a certain way, one could use that language to argue that it is *debugging* questions, not *conceptual* questions, that should be considered off-topic, because by their nature they have a high risk of not being particularly useful for other people. I know if I had to pick between the two, at least I would vote to keep conceptual/teaching questions, and do away with debugging questions.

Furthermore, the help center page on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) along with the [blog post on good subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) specifically mention that good conceptual questions *tend to be long, not short*. While true that this is specifically focusing on subjective questions, the same premises hold true for any type of question - we want *all* answers to explain "how" and "why" the answer is true; we want *all* answers to explain *in detail* what the answer is.

---

As far as the desired goal based on your question and comments, from what I can tell you are wanting to prevent people from coming here at all when their goal is to learn how to program on a broad scale. The short answer is:

#### We can't.

Until Stack Overflow controls the education systems of every country in the world, or until we institute a rigorous training regimen that all users most go through before they can join the site, ask a question, or post an answer, we simply will never be in a position to *prevent* people from having a misconception about the site before they ask their first question. Currently, we don't even know someone exists until they post their first post here.

As far as I'm aware, what constitutes *depth* in a discussion is not something we have yet been able to teach a machine or system, so there is also no way for us to detect the difference between asking about some implementation of a function from Facebook's website, or asking us how to write a Facebook-killer social network from scratch. We can write as much copy as we want in our Help Center about what to ask, but the more we write, the less people pay attention to it.

So... handling peoples' misconceptions is already an *ex post facto* problem, and simply re-defining some words or rewriting a help page won't do anything to change that.

As far as your *specific* example goes, I agree with your self-characterization of not being a wordsmith, because:

> However, questions which ask the community to fundamentally teach you a new concept are frowned upon, simply because it takes a lot of energy—on both sides—to be sure that the concept is properly communicated.

Frankly, this just sounds like you are too lazy to put in the effort to provide a comprehensive answer to a concept question. Which, if that's the case, that's fine! No one is forcing you to answer every question :-) But I think it's totally wrong to try and prevent *others* from teaching their peers or peer-hopefuls if they want to. Questions like these are great teaching questions, and should never be discouraged here:

- [What is a retpoline and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089426/what-is-a-retpoline-and-how-does-it-work)
- [What's the difference between implementation and compile in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle)
- [What does C++ syntax “A::B:A {};” mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546616/what-does-c-syntax-aba-mean)
- [Do lambda expressions have any use other than saving lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407180/do-lambda-expressions-have-any-use-other-than-saving-lines-of-code)
- [Difference in C# between different getter styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047721/difference-in-c-sharp-between-different-getter-styles)

(notice these are all very recent ones *and* with a very high score, since you criticized Mark Amery for providing some older questions in his earlier answer).

By all means, though, feel free to start an initiative to spread the word on Reddit, Twitter, coding forums, etc. that SO is not a teaching institution but rather a narrow help site in Q&A form... maybe it will make a difference and change the general public's perception of Stack Overflow, but I doubt it; I think people will disagree either silently or loudly.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't need to control every education system in the world to tell people in polite terms, "Hey, if you're looking to start on something big and you have *no clue* where to begin, you're not going to find much value in our community."

Comment: Further, I genuinely feel like you're somewhat ignoring my main point.  People come here with an expectation to be taught; that is, they expect expert answers to teach them a new thing.  I don't deny that teaching happens at *some* level.  What I vehemently reject is forcing our community to cater to users who explicitly only ever want to be taught everything without putting effort into their own work.

Comment: Yes, the close reasons address the issue, but they address the issue *after the fact*.  This is an attempt to address it *beforehand*.

Comment: @Makoto All of that is either already done or I have addressed in my answer why it is not feasible to be done.

Comment: @makoto The community can't be *forced* to cater to questions it doesn't want to support.

Comment: @CindyMeister:  Then we run the risk of running afoul of the new CoC when we attempt to defend our position on why we don't want to answer that kind of question.  It's kind of a Catch-22; I had drummed this up before the CoC was posted, but now that it's *up*, some of my concerns are starting to come to light.

Comment: @Makoto I don't buy that for two reasons: 1) You don't have to be rude or violate the Code of Conduct to defend an opinion on what kind of content you think is appropriate for the site. 2) You don't have to defend an opinion anyway; you can believe it silently.

Comment: None of us are employees. No one can force anyone to answer questions they don't want to. If the owners decide the site should be a "free for all", with no quality controls, those who have contributed to giving the site the reputation it has will eventually no longer support it and will find another home. What I find most odd is that, if they really want to provide a venue for everyone is that they insist on it all being in the "professional" venue, rather than opening a "for the masses" sub-site <shrug> SO is a symbiotic relationship that's starting to turn parasitic, sadly.

Answer (score 6):

I started out in comments, but that is too small...

Background: In reply to a comment I made about this problem falling under the category "too broad", the OP replied we need to catch these things before they get posted to the site. My reaction to that was "IMO a majority of the people who ask these kinds of questions won't understand the kind of text you propose because they simply lack the necessary technical background. I'm not sure it's possible to prevent it." To which Makato said s/he fears that then the damage may already be done. Going from there...

Not sure how you mean that, @Makoto, but I think the problem is the way global culture is developing. Writing code used to be something you needed resources for (main frames). Then PCs came along and it became less exclusive, but still required money+"passion" (Bill Gates, Steve Jobs came from this era). This was followed by the "Basic" langauges  making access to coding more accessible "to the masses", and on it went.

On the support side, we went from heads together around a table in the University computer building, to dial-up modems and CompuServe. It cost money to carry on a discussion, band-width was at a premium, we learned how to ask questions and convey information efficiently.

Then we got newsgroups, followed by forums and most people could be on-line all the time. The result was more verbiage and more people participating. I noticed a difference in what kinds of people asked questions and HOW they were asked already in the move from CompuServe to newsgroups. As soon as forums started supporting formatting, graphics, etc. the culture changed yet again - became more open.

Nowadays small children are introduced to the coding concepts. People Tweet (or whatever - I don't try to keep up with that short-lived stuff). Things on-line are (too) often free of charge and generally, there are no rules. "Everyone" encounters coding in school, at some level. I have no idea what the various college level curriculums require in the way of computer sciences, these days. But based on the types of questions I see here, I imagine a lot more non-nerdy people need to or are encouraged to sign up for "programming" than ever before. It's "where the money is", so people with less talent try to make their way.

All these things influence how people think, how they communicate by the written word, what their expectations are - how they view the world.

More and more people are coding who come from a non-professional and non-technical backgrounds. Yet, they still ask for (or demand) help from an on-line source - and expect it to be free of charge in a "wild west" (no rules) environment. That's why I don't think the proposal for Help content is going to alleviate the problem described. It won't "speak" to those who need to hear it.

About the only thing I can think of is that someone's first question MUST go through a review process before the question is posted to the site and before the person can have full membership. A person with knowledge in that area (say, a bronze badge, minimum) would have to review, explain what the short-comings are and how to make the question acceptable.

Some people will accept that, learn from it and gain access to the site. Others will turn away (complaining bitterly).

Or, I think we have no choice than to leave things more or less as they are.

Comment: I like how this answer touches on "entitlement culture" - what I'd term a "first world privilege". You are right, 10 years ago programming was niche. Today it's taught in schools and used by non-experts across industries. Many of those who program in sql, regex, python (to name a few) aren't professional or enthusiast programmers. They have other day jobs or interests, but circumstances have meant they have to do use these technologies..

Comment: ..They will continue asking questions whether or not they are in-scope. In my opinion, the new wizard will help, but it'll never be a complete solution. Currently, it's pretty hard to close poor questions in many tags, comments are over-emphasized, and the concept of voting is not appreciated by the twitter generation. The accessibility of SO naturally encourages users beyond the professional & enthusiast. We need to be able to better mange all user's expectations and make sure responses (e.g. post closure) are *timely* as well as appropriate.

Comment: While I respect and largely agree with your perspective, if we leave things largely how they are, then experts are going to stop caring about this place, and those of us who want to curate the place will be vilified and eventually forced out as well.  Getting it through to people that they can't just come to SO and expect us to teach them a new thing is a culture shift, and it's not just for the OPs out there, but it is for us as well.  We should do *something* about this.

Comment: @jpp the concept of voting is also not important for these people because they aren't "invested" in the site. It's not "home" and not a resource they rely on. But I think that's true, generally, whether the topic is politics, or schools... On the whole only a minority of people get involved.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I partially agree with you. But I also think that negative marks are hard-wired in this generation as *personal*. Even if downvotes only cost 0.01 it wouldn't make a difference, the fact that *someone* thought your question was poor is deemed a personal affront. There's no downvote button on twitter..

Comment: @Makoto Mmm, well, as you can tell, I've migrated through various venues (Compuserve, newsgroups, MSDN, now here). Each time, it was culture-shift that forced the change (Microsoft stopped supporting the venue). So let's just say I wouldn't be surprised if those who currently support this site end up migrating elsewhere, to a more "comfortable" environment, if the "Powers that be" don't want to regulate participation here more than they appear to.

Comment: @jpp I'm not worried about down- or up-voting as far as this topic is concerned. For me, personally in terms of site moderation, those are just indicators when I go through a list of questions which ones may need close votes (or need to be up-voted if the person has improved their question). But on that topic, it would help (as has been proposed) that we get a notification when an OP has edited their question so that we can upvote and/or remove a close vote. I'm more concerned about bringing along those who TRY than trying to stop those who won't.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly as I said in my answer, namely "Until Stack Overflow controls the education systems of every country in the world, or *until we institute a rigorous training regimen that all users most go through before they can join the site, **ask a question**, or post an answer, we simply will never be in a position to prevent people from having a misconception about the site before they ask their first question*."

Comment: @jpp On Twitter, disagreements or criticisms are often handled by quote-tweeting and other general forms of gaslighting. Not exactly a good alternative...

Comment: @TylerH, Your point and mine aren't mutually exclusive. Twitter may have an alternative way of expressing disagreement *and* promote a belief that "likes" are judgements on people, just like "downvotes" are deemed judgements on someone's quality on SO.

Answer (score 0):

> The best questions we have on our site are questions which are looking for help. That is, they're looking to solve a particular and specific problem and don't require us to author miniature lectures on the subject.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda) that is not aiming at a solution to solve a particular and specific problem and that has lots of great answers (in my opinion) lecturing about a basic concept. Aren't Q&A's like that one very valuable content on Stack Overflow?

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51167015/2564301)  is a question that *is* "looking for help" to "solve a particular and specific problem", and lo and behold, it did not require a lecture. All it needed was someone who writes the code for that OP.

Comment: @usr2564301 55 minutes and the linked post is gone

Comment: @Christophe: good thing there is [no shortage of fresh examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51172579/2564301) then.

Comment: What are the down votes expressing? That the Q&A I linked to it not valuable content? That I'm missing the point? Something else? I'm honestly interested.

Comment: @anothernode I guess they might be expressing that this would've been better as a comment, or perhaps that it's entirely superfluous since it doesn't add anything beyond what other answers, including mine, have already added. (FWIW, I've neither upvoted nor downvoted.)

Comment: @MarkAmery Thanks for you reply, really appreciate it! I can see that my answer doesn't add anything essential to yours. Although I think down voting is a little bit unfair in that case since our answers were posted almost simultaneously, as far as I remember, and all the other ones came later. But, of course, it's not such a big deal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate premise:

### "Those who *ask questions* on S.O. use it *to solve immediate problems.*"

### "Those who *read answers* on S.O. use it *as a place to learn*."

These are 2 distinct user groups, with distinct goals & priorities.
What makes for the "best answers" for each use case is likewise distinct.

Learning is a *potential* side effect - not necessarily the #1 goal. Those asking often have pressing deadlines, or a misunderstanding of site norms, and "*just want my code to work, pls halp!*" They don't necessarily care how or why it works, as long as it *does*.

If that doesn't mesh with "Stackoverflow's purpose in the world," then maybe it shouldn't have tried to become the defacto global repository of answers to programming questions. Where else are people supposed to ask?

> The best questions we have on our site are questions which are looking for help. That is, they're looking to solve a particular and specific problem and don't require us to author miniature lectures on the subject.

Many questions are terrible precisely because they are too particular, specific, and narrow to be of any use to anyone but the poster. Many answers are likewise terrible for being terse, bespoke, one-offs that offer little in the way of explanation or justification.

Awful code that solves 1 unique case in an expedient (not always the 'best') way is rampant, because users aiming to solve an immediate problem don't necessarily care about the theory or best practices, while those answering them are just seeking upvotes & rep.

The "best answers," in my view, *are* the ones that take the time to lay out the concepts in an understandable way *illustrated with* the specific examples/question being addressed.

These answers offer alternatives, delve into historical background, and justify their choices with reasoned explanations. They go beyond merely "answering the question" to address incorrect assumptions and explain best practices not directly asked about. They "teach" - they don't just barf out a response and call it good.

Those detailed "mini lecture" responses are the answers that add lasting value to this site. Those responses facilitate learning by the other ??% of people who come here to "learn" and never ask a single question.

### On teaching new concepts

> questions which ask the community to fundamentally teach you a new
> concept are frowned upon, simply because it takes a lot of energy—on
> both sides—to be sure that the concept is properly communicated.

This is true, but hints at key issues that are perhaps being overlooked:

1. People don't know what they don't know, and cannot name what they don't know.
2. If it's truly a good fundamental explanation, multiple people and the community will benefit
3. A "correct" answer w/o understanding just encourages more bad questions.
4. Longtime users might have forgotten what it's like to not know what they know now.
5. The S.E. network is redundant, fractured, occasionally tribal, and confusing.

If you don't want the responsibility of explaining a concept to someone who isn't familiar with it, the solution is simple: don't answer their question. Also, don't become a teacher.

Expecting some research & effort on their part is fine, but there are limits.

I *cannot* research a topic I don't even know the name of. What should I randomly mash into Google that wouldn't be better answered here by a human who knows what it's called? Where do you think I end up once I get close to Googling what I'm looking for? Q&A sites! Which one? Oh, right ...

No really, which one? Stackoverflow, Info Security, Cryptography, DBA, Superuser, Ubuntu, Unix/Linux, Software Engineering, Comp Sci, Code Review, Quantum Computing, or the other umpteen-jillion programming-adjacent SE spinoff sites??

How am I, as a hypothetical new user, even supposed to decide *where* to post, much less specifically *what* or *how*, meeting exacting community standards on the 1st try or else getting down-voted to oblivion?

How am I supposed to recognize an obscure duplicate when I just learned what this thing is called, without "experts" to explain the connection? How am I supposed to extract the answer I need when the "duplicate" is 4 versions before the only one I've seen, and entire programming ecosystems have grown and died since the "canonical answer" was first posted? If I lack that institutional knowledge I need someone else to guide me. I can either ask, which is the purported "purpose of this site in the world," or I can muddle along aimlessly.

Putting the onus entirely on new users to formulate perfectly crafted questions on an unfamiliar subject, with literally dozens of different places to ask it and a good chance of being smacked for "doing it wrong" is part of what makes this an "unwelcoming" process.

Showing relevant/possible duplicate questions based on what you've typed so far is effective. In fact, it seems to work much better than a simple "search"! Starting to ask a question often surfaces enough relevant/related responses for me that I don't have to bother asking. But, I rarely get to that point anyway.

Typically, I learn what I need from the detailed, comprehensive "mini lecture" answers that pull all the information I need together in 1 place, as opposed to short snippets and vocabulary tests that send me down rabbit holes & off on wild goose chases.

Comment: What, too many words? I do ramble ... Care to explain downvotes? I believe the premise of the initial question misunderstands why & how different groups of people actually use this site. If reluctance to answer questions in detail boils down to "I don't wanna" ... well, then don't.