# Are we providing a service?

Tags: discussion

I was looking through some discussion in comments, where one user had feeling that others are playing mean games, and the following remark drew my attention:

> Playing a game with semantics to be painful is not a quality service

My question is not about that discussion, my question is more general: are those who answer questions expected do to that as a service?

If yes, then I believe this site should focus more on improving the quality of that service, as opposed to quality of bare information contained in question and answers (which is presumably determined by voting). This should be stated explicitly in some policy document, with some guidelines outlining the expected service level.

If no, as for example is expressed [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315041/43848), then again it should be mentioned in site documentation somewhere, so that people who ask questions will not have unreasonable expectations.

What do you all think?

Comment: Related - [a discussion which does suggest that we set some kind of expectation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370486/1079354)

Comment: And my question is 'are we setting expectations beyond just providing answers'? Helping is a loaded word...

Comment: Just one more thing in the SLA to define.  One thing out of a few hundred.

Comment: @artem: "*are those who answer questions expected do to that as a service?*" What does that even mean?

Comment: I mean, it can be interpreted like this: StackOverflow is hosting a portfolio of my answers in exchange for me providing a service of, um, providing these answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think OP means are the users posting answers expected to approach it as if the question asker is a customer and thus provide a certain amount of support. Is this correct, artem?

Comment: @BSMP yes that's basically correct.

Comment: @artem: ... that makes absolutely no sense. You can stop posting answers at any time and just walk away. Your answers will still be here. They don't time out if you don't keep answering questions or anything. You even still get rep from them years later. A user is not "posting answers" until they're actually answering a question. And once they've answered that question, they're not "posting answers" anymore, until they decide to answer another question.

Comment: "Your answers will still be here." - not if the account gets deleted. Then I can't claim them as my answers any more. Account deletion does not happen often, and it happens according to the rules, but the rules are changing with time.

Comment: @artem: Even deleting accounts does not delete the answers. It merely anonymizes them. And yes, rules can change with time. But since SO has existed for nearly a decade without moving *anywhere* in this direction, I see no reason to expect that it might happen. You're tilting at windmills.

Comment: I'm not tilting at windmills, I'm asking for clarification. I can live with implicit expectations, I think I can figure it out, but being stated explicitly in the rules will help in situations when people with different expectations start arguing.

Comment: 'expected to approach it as if the question asker is a customer and thus provide a certain amount of support' - cannot be done because there is no billing mechanism.on SO.

Comment: No. In my eyes it is not a service. It is a pleasure.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually an interesting question.  It's paradoxical for most of us, since by the raw definition, Stack Overflow really *is* a service.  We provide a good for coders of all walks of life everywhere, and we do it for free.

The important thing when it comes to services is to set expectations and set service-level agreements, or SLAs.  By and large these remain undefined; we get a lot of people coming to Stack Overflow with code and assignment dumps with no indication that the OP has at least attempted to solve their own problem, and we get overly broad questions which people still want us to answer.

And you  know what?  Some people will solve whatever problem they're asked, as you demonstrate with the linked answer, even if they might be too broad or otherwise off-topic.  People that don't really care that they're providing a service don't really care about SLAs or expectations; they're in it for their *own* motives.

It's fine to have your own motives for participating, but it does really beg the question of how we wrangle this all into one overarching goal and ensure that everyone that's participating keeps this in mind.

I haven't found an answer yet; the discussion I linked to in the comments is still very much up in the air and split *enough* that we're not going to have an answer for a while.

Answer (score 3):

> If no, as for example is expressed in this answer, then again it should be mentioned in site documentation somewhere, so that people who ask questions will not have unreasonable expectations.

I don't think this is necessary. I think the person you quoted was more likely trying to express that someone wasn't being helpful by arguing over semantics, not arguing that they are a literal customer of whomever they were replying to.

I have seen the argument that we, as in the users not Stack Overflow employees, need to provide better customer service but only by one or two users and it's been months (or years) since I've seen someone use that phrase in a literal, sincere way.

Most new users assume this is a forum and despite all the problems that causes, one thing that the Exchange sites do have in common with forums is that everyone is here voluntarily. I don't think many people think the users posting answers are required to do so because they're employees or as part of some agreement with Stack Overflow itself.

There's also nothing about what type of site this is or anything in the documentation that implies there's a certain level of service. There are rules for using the site but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think of it as those who answer questions are offering a service.  More so, we *are* the service.

I think of it in terms of say, a music venue.  A club offers the services, including the "experience".  If only three people showed up, not much of an experience.  But if a large number of people showed up for the show, each and every one of them is a part of the service of creating an experience.

Same with the site.  If only three people showed up to answer the onslaught of questions, I think it's fair to say the "service" wouldn't be much.  But many people show up and it is what it is.

But just like those that show up to the music venue, they are not responsible for the success of the service.  They are just participating to whatever extent there are rules and guidelines that are expected of them in regards to playing along.

Comment: The people that show up to the music venue are beneficiaries of the service of the music venue being there at all.  They're indirectly contributing to the success of the venue which would encourage them to come back year after year.  Music venues don't just spontaneously appear and don't keep spontaneously appearing unless there's a dedicated following for them.

Comment: Contribution to success does not equate to responsibility of the success.