# How should SO be used? (drawing the line between assisting with specific problems and referring to generalized answers)

Tags: discussion

*NOTE: I'm not trying to be inflammatory or contradictory with this question. I genuinely want to understand.*

---

Now that I've explored Meta a bit, I keep seeing a surprising comment on the purpose and use of Stack Overflow. It usually goes something like:

> Stack Overflow is not a personal help desk for solving individual problems. It is meant to be a useful reference.

Given the *overwhelming* majority of questions and answers that go against that policy (at least the way I'm interpreting the questions and answers), it makes me wonder what Stack Overflow is supposed to be exactly and how it's supposed to be used.

More specifically, if a question is about a specific personal programming problem, how are we supposed to respond to it?

It appears that marking as a duplicate is a common practice, but sometimes, there isn't a duplicate for that specific problem. Only a somewhat related question that may or may not actually be helpful (but gets marked as a duplicate anyway).

I've also seen some even suggest turning SO into a reference guide by finding the most general version of the question, and editing both the question and answer so that they give good general advice about how to solve those problems, and *then* marking the question as a duplicate of the more generalized question/answer.

But if that is the case, then wouldn't it be easier to simply have a collection of community created language and IDE usage references that most questions can be directed toward? (like a wiki)

For example, if someone is having a null pointer error in an array manipulating loop, wouldn't it be easier to refer the asker to a reference on null pointers, a reference on array manipulation, and a reference showing how to use their IDE to debug issues, all in their current language?

I ask because from what I'm seeing, it's more useful to do either one (be a help-desk) or the other (be a reference). Trying to be both results in a lot of frustration between the users to see SO from opposing perspectives, usually between the majority of users who see Stack Overflow as a help-desk and the longstanding users who see Stack Overflow as a programming reference.

The question and answer format makes it clear that it isn't simply a reference, but the way it's moderated makes it clear that it isn't exactly a help-desk either. So what is it exactly?

I guess my question really breaks down as: Where does one draw the line between assisting with a specific problem and simply referring to (or just giving) a more generalized answer?

Comment: Stack never tried to be a help-desk. People are too stubborn to NOT use it as that though.

Comment: @Patrice - But that's what I'm asking. What exactly is SO trying to be?

Comment: A high level, low signal to noise ratio, repository of programming knowledge. The issue is that, when first interacting with the site, most users go "Google problem -> find Stack answer -> Resolve problem", people then think Stack is a help desk, and they start interacting with it like it is

Comment: @Patrice SO has made a number of changes and statements that move it away from being a reference source and more of a help desk.  It's not strictly mis-use.

Comment: @Patrice - I understand that. I already know that. What I'm asking is what it's supposed to be instead. The question and answer format makes it clear that it's not just a reference, but the way that it's moderated makes it clear that it's not a help-desk. So what is it?

Comment: @Patrice, drop the first step and it's correct.

Comment: @DragandDrop I'd be surprised that people don't LOOK for their answer and just magically open Stack ;)  (but I do get your point :P )

Comment: @Danegraphics Stack was built to be what I said.... That was the very intent of the creators when they started Stack... to me, it seems like it's still the intent

Comment: @Danegraphic, i think the line between specific and generalise is more fine that you think. Because we ask for minimal code for reproduction, it generalise the issue. It's not about the buisness object From "how to get xyz in unknow_object?"  but about "flatterning the list of properties of a nested object" for exemple

Comment: @Patrice - If it is meant to be a "high level, low signal to noise ratio, repository of programming knowledge", then why is it in question and answer format instead of say a wiki?

Comment: Go ask Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky maybe? I don't know the full story, but that's what they landed on.

Comment: @DragandDrop - That's a really good example. So there are specifics approached, but they are generalized as much as possible without losing specificity? And looking at it, I'm starting to realize that the other communities on the network don't tend to have the same problem that Stack does because programming isn't about generalities in the first place. Programming is all about being exact and specific.

Comment: You want to read up about the "Stack Overflow Documentation" debacle. It did not work. The advantage of Q & A is that it is usually pretty well-defined and small in scope, which makes it easily answerable. While a Wiki will be unfocused and too broadly scoped, or too much repetition of low-hanging fruit (or even just copy/pasting from other locations).

Comment: @Danegraphics Programming tends to lend itself to generalities just fine.  The other sites don't have the same problems as SO because they're so much smaller.  When 10% of your questions are duplicates it's way more of a problem when you're getting 5,000 questions a day then when you're getting 50.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - It appears that there might have been a few issues with how they were attempting to implement it. But that's interesting. So my question is, what do we do about all of the specific questions looking for specific answers, especially if they haven't been asked before? Do we give generalized answers or specific answers? Or both?

Comment: [*mumble mumble* codify the scope *mumble mumble*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370486/1079354)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/17034

Comment: @Makoto - That is an interesting discussion to read because it appears that everyone has a different place where they put the line. And on top of that, some people appear to have accepted and adapted to how SO is used, while others are more orthodox about SO being a generalized reference. So I guess in short, it shows that my question doesn't have an agreed upon answer yet.

Comment: @HansPassant - "Today, I'm not so sure anymore what they are trying to do." "SO users were afraid to ask questions, worried that not getting their ducks in a row before asking would get them responses that were intended to chase them away." - These are exactly my concerns. It appears that no one knows, and because of that, there is constant conflict about the correct way to handle things. Heck, even recent blogs by the staff appear to have longstanding users riled up because they disagree on these exact premises.

Comment: Oh, everybody knows, it merely depends on who you ask.  Everybody loves free beer, except those that have to brew it.  There have not been enough brewers around, SO needs twice as many to keep up with the thirst.  Some people worry about that a great deal, pretty big bummer when SO is out of beer just when you really need some.

Comment: @HansPassant - Well, "everybody knows" is probably a bit off. The majority of users come in with their own assumptions, the longstanding users disagree about the specific among themselves and have difficulty wording their views clearly to those who disagree, and the staff appear to be trying to appeal to both groups by being so general that contrary interpretations of official policy are allowed. I think a better wording would be "everyone has an answer, but those answers are all different".

Comment: As before, we are not a help desk.  There are aspects of help desk functionality, but assuming that's our entire purpose will do nothing but lead to frustration and suffering.  Making arguments that that's how people treat it, so that makes it valid, does nothing to help you, nor them, understand what SE is all about.

Comment: @fbueckert - I'm not saying that makes it valid. I'm saying that's how it's used. That's a reality that, while annoying, can't be denied. And two counterpoints: 1 - The best products are the products that work the way customers expect them to (most expect help desk here). 2 - SO is a community that rules by voting, and will thereby function by majority rule, regardless of moderation. By those two counts, SO is functioning almost exactly as it should, with only the longstanding members going against it. So until SO's actual purpose is made clear to ALL users, that's not going to change.

Comment: Just because someone expects a site to be a help desk doesn't automatically make it one.  Help desk features on a site also don't automatically make it one, either.  1.  Yes, I agree.  There are definitely changes that need to be made to make people aware that we're not a help desk, and never will be. 2. You say majority, I say uneducated.  They don't have the capability or privileges to enact changes (such as closing or reopening).  They invariably post on Meta something about downvotes, it gets shot down, the cycle continues.

Comment: @fbueckert - Well, if you have a clear view of what SO is *supposed* to be and how we can make sure it functions as such, I would love to hear it (in an answer). I've heard quite a few varying views so far. More can't hurt. (Also, saying "uneducated" is quite rude. Might want to tone that view down a bit in light of recent blog posts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the recent controversial blog posts about being "Welcoming", it looks like even longstanding users and staff disagree on what SO is supposed to be, especially when it comes to specific application of policy. And looking at some related questions in the comments, I see the same issue.

**So for now, the answer to your question is that there is no agreed on answer**. The community is in disagreement with itself about the specifics, leading to conflict between those who want to adapt to what the users want and those who want to have orthodox application of what they have interpreted the site's purpose to be.

It appears to be a debate between being "welcoming helpful", allowing all kinds of questions to be asked and answered (some consider to be "low quality"), and being "reference helpful", restricting the kinds of questions that are allowed to be asked (some consider to be unwelcoming).

Comment: Um, the blog posts don't actually involve that. The blog posts are about conduct, not content.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Given the debates about the blog posts (and other posts by the staff), it would appear that some people disagree. To some, it looks like the staff is starting to lean towards a more "help-desk" style approach to responding to questions. Especially with the idea of welcoming, one of the most unwelcoming things is being told that your question is bad, or unclear, or a duplicate of an unrelated question, all three of which are currently common practice. So one question is: Is SO staff asking us to abandon those standard practices designed to keep the site organized? Who knows?

Comment: @Danegraphics: "*Is SO staff asking us to abandon those standard practices designed to keep the site organized?*" They haven't asked us to do that. None of the comment templates on the recent "Welcome Wagon" posts represent abandoning standards; they're about not being jerks.

Comment: @NicolBolas - And that is your interpretation. What I'm saying is that there are other interpretations being debated, that being one of them. Even if that's not what they are asking, it has heavy implications regarding those practices, even if they aren't mentioned, specifically because those practices are often considered rude, unhelpful, and unwelcoming by a large portion of the user base.

Comment: @Danegraphics: "*What I'm saying is that there are other interpretations being debated,*" By whom? Where? And what are the *substance* of those arguments? Are those legitimate concerns, or are they just alarmism? The fact that there's an argument doesn't mean that there is actual controversy.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Controversy is defined by people having contradicting opinions on something, even if they aren't substantively based. Anyway, see this thread that got temporarily locked because of heated debate about "off-topic" things: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792/is-this-really-what-we-should-consider-unwelcoming - And this question that cites another "welcoming" blog post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370486/codifying-the-scope-differentiate-between-teaching-and-helping-on-stack-overflo?noredirect=1&lq=1 - Both pretty heated and everyone has different views.

Comment: @Danegraphics: It wasn't even locked for *10 minutes*. And it got a lock because the blog post got updated due to privacy concerns. And I find it difficult to characterize the second question as "everyone has different views". There are a lot of people with some views, and a far lower number (with fewer upvotes) who have different views. Your definition of "controversy" is poor because it allows *anyone* to manufacture a controversy just by vehemently disagreeing with someone else.

Comment: @NicolBolas - One of the big problems with meta is that, first, most normal users don't know it even exists, and second, any normal users that *do* know it exists quickly get their viewpoint of the website and its usage lambasted by downvotes (see literally any post questioning duplicate markings). So the contrary opinions on many topics debated here are very likely severely underrepresented for those two reasons. So upvotes and downvotes don't matter in this instance. If there is one person saying it, there are bound to be ten or more thinking it.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  My chief regret is not making the OP repost their answer and letting my hands go on autopilot when someone posts an answer in their question...