# How to ask for clarification from someone's answer

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a question about regularization, and I had multiple questions about the answer posted (which was copied from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-in-machine-learning-76441ddcf99a.) link).

However, when I asked for clarification, the answerer essentially said that I needed to demonstrate a better understanding of the topic. Needless to say, no clarification was given. Now, I only have 5 rep and the answerer has 300, so I am probably in the wrong. In the future, how should I ask for clarification?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300347/plain-english-description-of-regularization?noredirect=1#comment89585706_51300347) is the post.

Comment: '*Now, I only have 5 rep and the answerer has 1k, so I am probably in the wrong.*' - Reputation does not determine right and wrong.

Comment: You link to a comment from someone else than the one that provided the answer. Also I don't see anyone with 1k rep there (answerer has 374)

Comment: @AndréKool My mistake. I will update it

Comment: What is this meta effect on the answer ? Is there a valid reason there?

Comment: @DragandDrop what do you mean by meta effect?

Comment: What went wrong here is explicitly warned about in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much".

Comment: @RishabhMandayam the meta effect is the additional attention that a question/answer will get when you post a link to it here. There'll be lots of people coming to look at it and many of them might decide to vote on it.

Comment: 300 rep just means something like a dozen decent answers, a half dozen good ones, or one great one. So, you can probably learn from the answerer, but you shouldn't assume he knows everything there is to know about how Stack Overflow works, or should work. I mean, you shouldn't assume that even for someone with 500K or a mod icon (at most you should take that as a sign to double-check or further research to make sure you're right, not to automatically assume you're wrong), but someone with 300 is not that far from where you are.

Comment: Sorry, but that question is just way too broad for Stack Overflow. Please see [this recent SO Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370486/codifying-the-scope-differentiate-between-teaching-and-helping-on-stack-overflo).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Now, I only have 5 rep and the answerer has 1k, so I am probably in the wrong.

As mentioned in my comment: Reputation does not determine right and wrong.

> In the future, how should I ask for clarification?

Neither of you did anything wrong. *You* asked for a clarification and *they* were well within their rights to *respectfully* decline or entirely ignore your request. Instead they provided some information which again they don't *need* to do.

### How would you improve?

Your request for clarification was fine but what your real focus should be is your question as it is too broad. I too would have suggested for you to learn the basics and then formulate a more specific question.

Comment: If I had more than 8k rep, I'd probably disagree, but now I have no other choice but to +1

Comment: @Adelin Why would you disagree if you had more than 8k rep? Reputation only means that someone has provided well-received, helpful/interesting answers or questions. *If* they are active in a tag related to the subject in question there may also be a good chance that they are actually versed in that subject, but that is not guaranteed, and anyone can be wrong. I know I've been repeatedly.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you do not get it, Adelin has used sarcasm.

Comment: @Xenolion *"We are Germans and we use Unix. That's a combination of two demographic groups known to have no sense of humour whatsoever."* (Hanno Müller in dcoup)

Comment: Generally speaking it is advisable to use a "smiley" to indicate that you are making a joke.  Sarcasm that is not intended to be funny is probably "not nice".

Comment: @StephenC was that a sarcastic dig at the new "unwelcoming" blog post?

Comment: No.  It was a simple straight statement.

Comment: @StephenC You're being too conservative.

Comment: If on the other hand you have 1 rep and the answerer has 1M, now that's a different matter.

Comment: @MrLister I can't tell if that's is sarcasm or not.