# How can I request "simpler" answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Sometimes I ask questions, and get answers that assume that I know a lot more than I do.  To be clear, I am not a "beginner programmer" in general (I have been programming for years and have (multiple) degrees).  Still, I am not omniscient, and there are topics in which I *am* a beginner.  Despite the fact that I am not a total noob, I sometimes feel unequipped to parse answers to questions when I am not well-versed in the subject matter.  This presents a Catch-22:  In order to understand the answers, I need to become an expert in the subject, but if I were an expert in the subject, I would not be asking the question in the first place.

This is especially the case when there are "existing questions/answers" that ostensibly answer my question, but they are currently above my head, as the original question was asked by a non-noob, and the relevant answers respond to the question assuming that the reader is a non-noob.  The duplicate questions *do*, technically, "answer my question", but they don't help me out, because I need it explained like I'm five.  My recent experience was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131756/how-to-access-self-in-javascript-class), from which I was directed to several other questions and answers.  I'm sure the info I need is in there somewhere, but I think I will need to ask 10 other questions and to read a book on the history of JavaScript before I can tease it out.

What is the best etiquette to request answers that target "noobs"?

Comment: You can always post a comment under an answer pointing out that the explanation is too difficult. The author can rethink it an provide a simpler explanation.

Comment: Technically, all answers target noobs. Some just miss the target.

Comment: Perhaps Stack Overflow is not the right medium (e.g., to learn programming one question at a time)? Perhaps a traditional forum or chat-like place is better suited? The back and forth required to understand an answer seems better suited to those kind of places. Stack Overflow *can* be used for self study by searching in the existing [23,127,380 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), but finding the right questions and answers may be a challenge.

Comment: " My recent experience was this question, from which I was directed to several other questions and answers. I'm sure the info I need is in there somewhere, but I think I will need to ask 10 other questions and to read a book on the history of JavaScript before I can tease it out." Did you try clicking the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345), clicking through to the [canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484), and starting with the top answer there, reading from top to bottom? If you did, specifically where did you get stuck? What question did you then have?

Comment: It is that age old question. Is it the responsibility of others to make you understand answers... or is it a signal you have your own responsibilities to address first? The answer should be obvious if you know that you don't ask questions for yourself, you ask them on behalf of the programming community. I.E. : the answers are not for you specifically.

Comment: @Gimby "the answer should be obvious" in my experience, the programming community is rife with beginners.  Any mathematician can talk to you about polynomials in a way that requires high school education, but also in a way that requires most of an undergraduate math degree, and some mathematicians can talk about polynomials in a way only they and 10 other people on the planet understand.  To suggest that it is somehow "wrong" to present the matter in *any* of those ways is incorrect.  All three groups are members of the mathematics community.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, I did.  Notice that neither of those questions nor their answers ever include a mention of `class`.  I know, in theory, that javascript `class`es are based on the `prototype` model, and that my question about `class` `field`s can therefore be answered by understanding this relationship.  OTOH, "how to access a class field" is, no joke, week 1 of intro Java programming.

Comment: @Gimby, FWIW, I'm only here after having read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) on the subject.  These are pretty straightforward.  In fact, the docs point out the problem I mention (hence my description), but they don't seem to address how to deal with it (hence my question).  If the questioner's "responsibility" to self educate doesn't have some kind of limit, then the Q+A site becomes moot: Everyone can simply answer their own questions.

Comment: If you want a simpler answer, you should ask a simpler question.

Answer (score 10):

If there is an obvious *next action*, no matter if it requires a lot of time, just do it. I.E. you asked what you think is a "perfect question" but the answers are hard to understand or adapt to your specific case or circumstances, and someway you conclude the answers are perfect too, but now you need to develop skills, then take a training, join a bootcamp, find a mentor, etc.

If there isn't an obvious *next action*, here are some SO features that might be helpful:

[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Use comments to ask the answer author to clarify / extend some point. Ask them to provide the source of their recommendations or references.

[Bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Offer a bounties using a custom reason. Explain why the current answers doesn't help, what they are missing, or what are your expectations.

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

- Post follow-up questions about one answer or a part of an answer that might be helpful for others. Include a link to the post that derived the follow-up question and clearly explain what difficulties are you facing. Do not include information about yourself, focus on the programming issue trying to generalize it so the question might help others.
- Carefully edit the question to <sup>from [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/289691)</sup>

  > ...*provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself*, or to explain why the existing answers didn't work.

  By "carefully" I mean without invalidating the current answers changing radically the question.

If you have doubts in a specific case about if posting a new question or making a edit, post a question in Meta including the link to the question.

[Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Look at the tag wiki. Some tag wikis explains basics concepts and include faqs and resources about them. Some also include a link to a chat room where you might find people willing to explain an answer, provide ad-hoc guidance, etc.

User profile

Look at the answer author profile. Some people include "faqs", links to a chat room that they participate frequently, etc.

Related

- [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/289691)
- [How to ask for clarification from someone's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370945/1595451)