# A little bit of more old-user-friendly (as a complement of a new-user-friendly)

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, comments

Today I came across this question: [Calculate the sum of each column of an HTML table in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048088/how-to-calculate-sum-of-each-column-of-table-in-typescipt). The poster has 47 rep (so, not a new user anymore), asks a question, and provides a screenshot of his code (see first revision).

To me it looks like *here is some shit, do it for me, I don't even dare to help you helping me*. I pointed this out in a (a little bit sarcastic) comment, and got another comment that I was rude. So, the reply I was about to give to that comment was

> @PatricioVargas well, is that rude? Maybe toxic a little, but the guy
>   asks for a free help, and the only thing he needs to do is to provide
>   [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Then I decided to first check in the *Ask question* form (I'm don't ask questions that often) whether all those

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

etc. are visible there.

To my surprise, **there is no direct link about how to ask questions there**.

I've seen a lot of posts that the Stack Overflow community is toxic and unfriendly especially to the new users; it does not accept newcomers, etc. That's why we introduced all those "New contributor" badges, those reminders to *avoid beating* newbies.

However there is no way those newbies can learn. The "be nice" policy is good only when it is bidirectional.

Half of the questions are literally trash and again and again somebody writes as a first comment 'Please add your code', 'How to reproduce this', 'What is your intention' etc.

But, wait a minute, it's not a paid on-call service. It should be first of all fun.

So, maybe the problem is not in the "New contributor" badges? Maybe the community would be more friendly if the questions were better?

There are lots of solutions, e.g.

- add links to "How to Ask"
- add reminders **to the questions**
- add the ability to push standard comments like 'please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask', 'please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)' etc. Of course, one can always make some sort of JavaScript bookmark to write such comments, but why not doing it as a part of the platform?

But, the primary is to care of quality of the questions in the first place. As long as a good question is almost an answer, it is quite important for a Q/A platform to have high quality questions.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Well if you think the be nice policy is good if it's bidirectional... why were you toxic yourself? Not the crux of your question, but you can't ask others to not be rude to you and then be allowed to be snarky, sarcastic, or toxic...

Comment: as I mentioned, I was totally sure that when you ask a question you have all recommendations on how to ask there. Now I know the sad truth and this post is trying to change that

Comment: @smnbbrv so? that doesn't change my question, or the point it's trying to make. Even if the user had all the recommendations, why does that absolves you from being nice? 2 wrongs don't make a right, and being rude to someone who you perceive to be rude to you is just not going to help

Comment: I think the comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379145/1197934) encapsulate expected behaviour towards users you believe aren't displaying enough effort rather nicely.

Comment: Adding to Martjin's comment, the Ask a Question page does include links to https://stackoverflow.com/help and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . (Could be based on rep or number of questions.)

Comment: You're not wrong exactly, but berating one person isn't appropriate and certainly isn't going to fix the systemic issues you point out (which, also, are well-known). Nicol Bolas expresses the problem well here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366774/603977

Comment: You might also be interested in [What does our long-term community need?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373158/)

Comment: How is the be nice policy directional? Old users aren't supposed to post rude comments. New users aren't either. No one is.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, your comment was rather snarky. Don't do that, there is no need to use snark, however frustrated you might feel when coming across someone posting a screenshot of code. Please assume good intentions, and *constructively* point out that screenshots are not acceptable here. I use

> Sorry, we [can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

whenever I come across such posts.

Note that new users are given an extra page before they can ask questions and are asked to tick a checkbox to acknowledge that they have read it. [That specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) includes information on how to ask good questions with further links.

In the end, not everyone reads everything given to them. That still doesn't excuse you from being rude or snarky, however, if low quality posts affect you so much that you can't keep your tone constructive, **then don't comment at all**, just use downvoting and closing to handle questions that don't meet our standards.

If that's still not enough to prevent you from using snark, then your next option is to **take a break from the site** and leave cleaning up to others for a while.

Comment: You can also just not comment, and downvote and close as applicable.

Comment: I got the message. Thanks.