# Request: edit/clarify the "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming" blog post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog, welcoming

**TL;DR**

I claim that several arguments made in the 
["Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change. "](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) blog post are
ridden with serious flaws (naive assumptions about human psychology, logical fallacies, 
questionable approaches to statistics). 
Furthermore, I have the impression that
one particular paragraph in this blog post 
presents certain unproven assumptions as
undeniable facts, and thereby precludes constructive discussion.

I propose that this paragraph (discussed in detail below) is either substantially 
reworded, or deleted altogether.

---

**EDIT_01 (reaction on debates in comment section)**

The focus of the question is **not "Where is the evidence?"**, the focus of the question is:

- **Do we agree that certain claims require evidence and careful analysis**

or

- **Do we want to insist that certain claims must be taken as undeniable facts and just *believed* without any evidence?**

It's all about this quote:

> When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done.

Believe or investigate? That's essentially the question. The rest of the post is an attempt to explain why I think the question is important, followed by a discussion of the paragraph in the blog post.

---

**Motivation**

I consider Stack Overflow community to be an important part of the broader 
community of people who are interested in programming.

This community was generous enough to share the best and latest tools with everyone in
the world. For decades, this community provided a seemingly infinite supply of compilers, 
build tools, operating systems, DBMSs and IDEs for free, from which everyone 
(including myself -- some random guy from the other side of the planet) could 
greatly benefit.

The members of this community also shared their ideas and technical expertise
(in form of freely available documentation, books, MOOCs, video lectures), 
with everyone who was willing to listen carefully to what they had to say.

Finally, when all the compilation error messages and books weren't enough, 
there were some online-forums, and later Stack Overflow, with people who
helped me out with my specific problem when I got stuck.

Never in my entire life has this community asked me *anything* about my
sex, gender, race, ethnicity, or nationality -- which is nice.
The community has also never asked me anything about my political views, my religion, or the levels of my 
political/religious/nationalistic fervor (or lack thereof) -- 
which is nice, but also surprising, because putting powerful 
tools in the hands of people you've never heard of seems to require 
tremendous amounts of faith in humanity.

Working with all those tools and compilers taught me how to think, and how
to tell apart what is correct from what is incorrect.
Reading all those books and documentation forced me to learn the English
language -- this is why I can share my opinions here. So much of my 
neural circuitry has been shaped by tools and ideas provided by this 
community, that I think it isn't too far-fetched to say that "I" wouldn't 
even exist without it, at least I wouldn't be the same person.

Therefore, my experience is that this community is not just *inclusive*,
but indeed it exerts a force strong enough to attract people born
on other continents who live in different cultures and speak different 
languages. 
Claiming that this community is not welcoming or not inclusive
seems outrageously unjust and completely absurd to me.

Likewise, it seems quite absurd to accuse the community of being elitist.
Where else in the entire human history could it happen that some low-rep
user from some foreign country thousand miles away could openly and 
publicly criticize the posting of a professional in a senior position
working for some major company, and that this professional would actually 
accept the criticism and update their answer?
The reason why the professional veteran user would go and update their answer 
without any further discussion is exactly because the status of the users 
doesn't matter when it comes to objective statements whether a piece of 
code compiles or not, or whether it contains a bug or not.

#### Analysis of the problematic paragraph in the blog post

The blog post seems to go beyond accusations of being insufficiently welcoming
and elitist. Even though it never says it directly, it seems to imply that
the Stack Overflow community as a whole has some severe problems with racism,
sexism, and in general with discrimination of certain minority groups.

I have the impression that it is even worse: not only does the blog post *raise*
those accusations, it also seems to try to force the reader to *accept* those
accusations as undeniable facts, without providing any evidence whatsoever.

The following paragraph (in combination with the section header) seems 
particularly problematic to me:

> **Yes, we really have a problem.**
>
> But how do we really know that too many developers experience Stack Overflow as an unwelcoming or hostile place? 
>   Well, the nice thing about problems that relate to how people feel is that finding the truth is easy. 
>   Feelings have no “technically correct.” 
>   They’re just what the feeler is telling you. 
>   When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. 
>   You’re done. And a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place. 
>   We know because they tell us.

This paragraph deserves detailed analysis.

1. The following claim seems to oversimplify human psychology quite a bit:

   > But how do we really know that too many developers experience Stack Overflow as an unwelcoming or hostile place? 
   >   Well, the nice thing about problems that relate to how people feel is that finding the truth is easy. 
   >   Feelings have no “technically correct.” 
   >   They’re just what the feeler is telling you.

   I don't think you could find any psychological literature that wouldn't directly *contradict* this statement. 
   Some people can fail to articulate their feelings properly. Some people can be manipulative. Some can even lie about their feelings.
   Even if they precisely describe their feelings, it is often not simple to
   infer the actual reasons for those feelings. For example, some people can complain about migraine and regularly hold furious speeches about
   how enraged they *feel* about the incompetence of their colleagues, only to find out later that the migraine is a somatic symptom of a masked depression, 
   and that their negative feelings are actually caused by unresolved conflicts from ten years ago, which had nothing whatsoever to do with their current colleagues. People aren't "Hello-World" one-liners. I think one should approach such statements a bit more carefully, and not jump to conclusions immediately.
2. The claim

   > a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place.

   (regardless of whether it is actually true or not), does not imply that

   > we really have a problem

   Suppose that you can experimentally show that programming Shaolin monks,
   when confronted with a wall of thousand `gcc` compilation errors in their code,
   remain calm and feel nothing but tranquility, whereas all other programmers
   experience varying levels of stress and anxiety. This experiment would show
   that Shaolin monks have better command of their feelings and emotions. It 
   would *not* prove that Richard Stallman is a Chinese nationalist
   who wrote a compiler that discriminates against all other programmers.
   Likewise, if members of certain minorities complain that Stack Overflow is 
   unwelcoming, it does not *imply* that they are actually treated differently.
   It could mean that the members of those minorities tend to react to
   the same circumstances differently, or that they tend to voice their concerns more
   often.
3. Finally, the following two sentences

   > When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. 
   >   You’re done.

   are the ones that I consider most problematic. 
   Is a site for technical questions really the most appropriate 
   place to ask for blind belief in extraordinary claims without
   providing any evidence? This sentence simply asks to accept all the accusations,
   just because some unnamed individuals feel in a certain way. 
   I don't see how any constructive discussion can take place 
   under such premises.

An important remark on the second point is in place: from "A does not imply B"
it does *not* follow that "A implies not B". There is no proof that people from certain minority groups are not treated differently.
Indeed, the discussion so far has brought several cases to my attention that
clearly show that there *are* problems, both with 
discrimination based on race and with 
discrimination based on sex or gender. 
But even if the conclusion is true, it does not automatically make an argument valid.

**Request**

I propose the deletion or substantial rewriting of the paragraph
discussed above, because it

- is built around questionable oversimplification of human psychology,
- contains inferences that seem invalid from logical and statistical point of view,
- states unproven accusations as if they were undeniable facts, 
  thereby precluding any kind of constructive discussion.

Furthermore, I propose either

- to provide some evidence that supports the apparent claim of the
  blog post that the hostility towards new users is caused primarily
  by rasist/sexist sentiments among Stack Overflow's core community

or

- to shift the focus of the blog post to the other (in my subjective opinion
  much more likely) cause of occasional hostility, namely the unwillingness
  of some new users to do their part of the job, and to invest enough effort 
  into formulating their vaguely defined problem as an answerable question.

The latter variant would also mean that one can concentrate the efforts on helping the new users to ask better questions, which I of course fully support.

One might also consider to unlink the blog post from the main page until
the obvious logical fallacies and incorrect facts are corrected.

**Related questions**

The question 
["How do you know Stack Overflow feels unwelcoming"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming/366733?noredirect=1#366733) quotes the 
same paragraph, and also asks for more evidence. It's not a duplicate, because 
I am not so much concerned about the lack of evidence as such, but instead I am more concerned about *those two sentences* that seem to insist that no evidence 
is necessary, that all accusations are self-evidently true, and that no
discussion is desirable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Too much ado about nothing.

Comment: @TGrif "How to conduct a discussion if the blog post seems to insist that accusations are undeniable?" Should I reformulate a posting tagged with `discussion` with a question. Sorry, I'm a noob on meta (let's see how that feels).

Comment: @brasofilo Accepted. Probably too long. I didn't have the talent to make it any shorter. I will put more effort into rewriting it to make it shorter and clearer; Do you think that the strategy "Accuse, insist that no proofs are necessary, explain the consequences of misbehavior" is an acceptable way to conduct a discussion? I somehow have a problem with that particular strategy.

Comment: They doth protest too much, me thinks.

Comment: @apaul Do you generally have something against protesting as such, or have I somewhere pointed out a logical fallacy where there is none? I know that I cannot express myself as elegantly as Shakespeare, but have I stated anything which is objectively not true?

Comment: @Andrey, I'm really at loss with all the hype. I gather some folks at the company want to do something about  something. They just dropped a blog post about it... and now?

Comment: @brasofilo If they simply announced some changes and implemented them, I wouldn't have said anything: none of my business. But I see how a huge group of people that have been quite welcoming to me are accused of being unwelcoming, and then are told that the accusations aren't even discussible. To support this claim they link an invalid argument on the main page of a site that is all about objectively valid things. I don't want to see any invalid arguments that seem to be based entirely on emotions of some unnamed people on the main page of a site that I visit frequently.

Comment: Nah, just pointing out that your protest in some ways demonstrates the issue. A bit like people in the US responding to "Black Lives Matter" with "All Lives Matter".  Obviously, all lives matter, but they're protesting someone's meaningful protest in a somewhat tone deaf way, and that's not really productive towards resolving the issues at hand.

Comment: @apaul I didn't claim that someone's opinion doesn't matter, or that someone's life doesn't matter. Indeed I've followed the discussion for quite a while, and I'm genuinely thankful for bringing some issues to my attention. But even if the author wanted to bring attention to an important issue, it does not automatically make the argument valid. And I'm nowhere near the US, and I don't really appreciate when the style of heated debates from US politics is brought to a website that is entirely about objectively solvable technical issues. But thank you, I will update my posting.

Comment: "objectively solvable technical issues" see there's the problem... People feeling discriminated against isn't exactly a technical issue. Not all problems are as easy or strictly logical as your typical programming issue. Feelings aren't variables that you can dump into a function. They're not exactly quantifiable. And they're much harder to sort.

Comment: @apaul But the structure of the argument does not depend on the exact content! If you substitute monks instead of some other minority, the argument remains invalid. If you replace the "feelings" by exactly quantifiable heart rate, the argument still remains invalid. Furthermore, the blog claimed that the problems with feelings are very easy: people tell you something, therefore it's true. Which one is it now?

Comment: @apaul: "*People feeling discriminated against isn't exactly a technical issue. Not all problems are as easy or strictly logical as your typical programming issue.*" Sure. But that doesn't mean that it can't be debated. The thing about Black Lives Matter is that they can point to *actual quantifiable problems* that they're protesting. As of yet, we haven't seen actual quantifiable problems in this domain on Stack Overflow. On IPS and certain other sites, yes; sexist/racist things have happened there. But those are *quantifiable*; you can point to actual posts that happened.

Comment: @apaul: At present, any gender/racial/etc bias on SO is determined entirely through *feelings*. You cannot debate feelings. You cannot quantify them. You cannot even *analyze* them. If you arbitrarily decide that certain people's feelings matter more than others, then you give those people power *over* those others. It turns into "do what these people tell you or you're a sexist pig/racist scum".

Comment: If loads of people are telling you roughly the same things, at great length, over and over again, for years, it may not be strictly "true", but it may be a strong indicator that there's something worth taking a hard look at.

Comment: @apaul: What things have we been told "over and over again"? That SO isn't welcoming to new people? Yes, we've heard that before, more often than not in defense of bad posts. That SO is biased against women/POCs? That's a new one that I've literally never heard before that blog post. IPS, yes, they have problems with that (and again, specific incidents can be cited). But not about SO.

Comment: @apaul There are loads of people telling you this? Perfect! Show me those people! Then I would have to  **unpack the magnifying glass**, and take a really close look at the evidence. But the blog suggest the opposite: it tells me that no analysis of the evidence is necessary.

Comment: I've heard the gender bias issue come up more than once. @NicolBolas

Comment: @apaul: On Stack Overflow? OK, let's start there: give me some information about that incident.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Women It's really that easy... @NicolBolas

Comment: Does anyone has a bookmark for the "4 stages of a regular SO user"? I think *Passion* and *Cynism* were the extremes...

Comment: @apaul, Nicol Bolas. Edited question. My main concern is not that there is no evidence. My main concern is that the blog post insists that no evidence is required, and that we should simply believe that there is a problem.

Comment: Note that my answer does not address the "Request" part of your question. I feel the request detracts from the rest of your post. It is, so to say, a rhetorical [feature-request].

Comment: Why would anyone lie in a non-public survey about how welcome they feel on SO? What could they possibly gain from lying? This sounds more like denial because it makes you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @shogged When a person is faced with the problem: *"Something is wrong. I could try to figure out whether it's my fault, or whether it's because some external system discriminates against me"*, the answer *"It's probably something wrong with the external system, it's racist/sexist"* is easy and does not require much effort on part of the person having this problem. This thought actively helps conserve energy in the short term. And biological systems really like to conserve energy. This could lead to a self-reinforcing loop, where this thought is applied whether it's appropriate or not.

Comment: @shogged I don't claim that it's exactly this person's fault, or that there are some bad intents behind it. But if you train the entire generation of people to be really sensitive to those issues, it could occasionally happen that in some persons, this self-reinforcing energy-conserving loop is activated. It might be just an unexpected & unwanted side effect of educating the population about those issues: some "classifiers" (people) could be trained to have too high sensitivity, and to produce false-positives too often.

Comment: @shogged Coupled with other reinforcing effects (e.g. media really liking to broadcast spectacular stories about all kind of nasty thing people do to each other, with cases of racism and sexism being considered to be interesting stories to report about), this could lead to a discussion that is unnecessary heated up. That's at least what it looks like to an observer from the outside.

Comment: @shogged If you then additionally take into account that there are entire departments in the universities that specifically educate people about how to stand up against discrimination of all sorts, and to argue about it effectively, it seems plausible, that this must lead to occasional overreaction. Stack overflow just turns out to be a place where such overreaction seems particularly strange, because it's decisively unclear why someone would discriminate against rectangular identicons with names like "user23456789".

Comment: @shogged I have to emphasize again: the fact that some people are very sensitive to those issues, and occasionally produce false-positives, does *not* imply that the issues aren't real. As I said above: there is considerable evidence (even though anecdotal so far) that those issues indeed are real. In the answers and comments in other threads I saw frustrated female users renaming their accounts to neutral names, and example of blunt antisemitism: I'm not in **denial**, I see this. But that's not my point. My point is that one has to take the magnifying glass out, and investigate it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin *"Something is wrong. I could try to figure out whether it's my fault, or whether it's because some external system discriminates against me", the answer "It's probably something wrong with the external system, it's racist/sexist"* That sums up most of the objections to this blog post.

Comment: @shogged Not sure how to interpret it, because you truncated my sentence exactly there where the interesting part began. I didn't claim that *"It's probably something wrong with the external system"* is always the right answer, I said that this line of thought is a good strategy for conserving energy in the short term. I should also have said that this strategy can actually be good and helpful for regaining emotional balance when people are faced with *actual* discrimination. But it can also go terribly wrong when applied pervasively to all aspects of life, including programming.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that much of the heated discussion on meta was *caused* by these unjustified claims. The problems of conflating and implicit accusations *could* have been discussed in a far more calm and civilized way. But the "feelings + magnifying glass" part nipped every sensible discussion in the bud. Trying to restrain people from speaking their minds causes exactly the back-pressure that we now observe on meta. I think that the request of substantially rewording the blog post is more than justified, and it could be done without affecting the goal of being more welcoming to newbies.

Comment: @Marco13 I think it's simpler than that. Conservatives have been primed to be outraged and insulted by anything they perceive as "SJW", and this blog triggered them. Look at how many assumed it was a personal attack on their own conduct.

Comment: On the meta sites, suggestions/initiatives are often accepted if they are posted as questions. This post obviously seeks input. I see no reason to close it as "not a question", although it may be too broad.

Comment: @shogged This is discussed elsewhere ad nauseam, but it is not the point of this question! This question/request aims at alleviating *severe* technical flaws of the blog post. As such, of course, it is not a "question" (in the same way as a "burnination request" is not a "question"). But it is a request that aims at making the discussion more open, neutral and objective, which would be highly desirable, as far as I'm concerned...

Comment: @shogged Are you now conflating me with the conservatives from the US? First, I've never been anywhere near US, and second, I'm very far from the conservatives. In particular, I really don't want that SO is transformed into a Twitter-like burning battleground between "SJW"s and "conservatives" - it's off-topic, it's polarizing, it's distracting, it's emotionally draining, and those endless discussions seems to never lead to anything. I just don't like all of it, I don't want to see anything of this here.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin no, but you were kinda easily triggered by their mere mention.

Comment: @shogged When/where was I "triggered" by their mere mention? If you mean my previous comment, then I'm more "triggered" because you mention the "conservatives", because if conservatives (the really loud ones) show up here, then I really don't know what to do... I would therefore propose to choose the words more carefully, to use valid arguments, and refrain from making extraordinary claims without providing any evidence. If there is an actual problem, I think that SO has enough problem solving skills on its own, and does not have to resort to heated political debates.

Comment: @shogged As much as I disagree with the premises of this question (cf. my answer), Andrey is absolutely right with respect to those last few comments. Political polarisation and labelling do not help, let's try not to worsen the climate of discussion here.

Comment: To address one of your early points, in fairness, many of the early software tools shared by the programming community from the early decades onward were shared not out of "generosity," but for recognition. In many cases, generosity had nothing to do with it. The same can be said for some of the responses on SO.

Comment: @TaW Excuse me, I can't quite follow. Who are "the meta-nerds"? Am I a "meta-nerd" who is misreading anything? Or are those who posted the blog the "meta-nerds"? I don't think that closing Meta for a year altogether is **not** a very constructive proposal...

Comment: SO doesn't "feel" unwelcoming, it IS unwelcoming (to 'bad' questions). The closest thing to a welcome most new users get is "Welcome to SO, here's a link to read to tell you what you're doing wrong". That's a best-case scenario. Whether that's good or bad or should be changed is a different question.

Comment: It would depend: Do you spend more time here than on SO? Are you in denial of the problems mentioned in the blog?

Comment: @TaW I usually prefer to answer actual questions about programming, and rarely look at Meta. I am not in denial of the problems mentioned in the blog, because I've myself flagged rude racist comments on several occations, and regularly edit out greetings that exclude people of certain genders. So, no, I'm not in denial of the problem (see also my comment 5h ago). I still have problems with the structure of the argument. Am I a meta-nerd now, or what? Or a weird outlier?

Comment: > I don't think you could find any psychological \[ed: or sociological\] literature that wouldn't directly contradict this statement. ... I don't think you could find any such literature \(other than just statistics\) that is worth more than the paper it's printed on. And most of it isn't even on paper. Because 99.99% of psychology is basically made up off the cuff to fit the case\(s\) at hand.

Comment: He lost me at "Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, ***women, people of color***, and others in marginalized groups.". This statement is ridiculous and it's the fourth line of that blog post.

Comment: @Knu The same statement is repeated later, in bold font, which makes the focus of the blog post pretty clear, but maybe it's just my perception playing tricks with me?

Comment: The real question is: who vets the blog posts made by the Executive Vice President? The CEO?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin nah [Jay has an Honors B.A. in Drama](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management), he knows his shit.

Comment: @DaveCousineau, I don't disagree, but is that unwelcoming because the poster is something other than a white male, or is it because there is a deeply entrenched feeling of "RTFM"? I admit that I do not EVER go to meta sites, but do use SO regularly as a consumer of answers (usually to others questions) and have never encountered a situation where one was berated or otherwise treated badly BECAUSE OF their gender/ethnicity/race/religion/soft drink choice/comic choice/etc. I will say that there is, IMO, a disturbing trend (generally) of "You were mean to me, therefore you are a racicst/sexist."

Comment: @apaul: _"They doth protest too much, me thinks."_ You seem to be insinuating that the OP is racist and/or sexist. Might want to be more careful with that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) I think you are reading too much into it. I think it was meant more like  "can't we all just be a bit more compassionate, and accept the conclusion of the blog without too much nitpicking". 2) Even if the conclusion is correct, and even if actual racists or sexists protest against the conclusion, it *does not automatically make the structure of the argument valid*.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: I haven't made any comment about "it". I responded directly to a comment by apaul. Did you mean to comment to somebody else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, that's how I interpreted the Shakespeare quote: as a request to stop nitpicking and to accept the conclusion of the blog-post, not as an insinuation of any sort. Sorry if my comment was confusing. I just want to avoid stacking meta-meta-accusations that someone insinuated that someone else insinuated that someone accuses someone to be racist or whatever... As long as they don't point out any concrete "bugs" or false statements in my posting, I don't care too much.

Comment: @ntwrkguru I actually missed that this had anything to do with race/gender/etc. I don't think I've seen anything specifically racist/sexist before. SO is unwelcoming to everyone that asks "bad" questions. The only way race has anything to with it is maybe when the OP barely speaks English. (But that's not really racist; and people are actually still surprisingly willing to answer barely decipherable questions to milk any rep gains they can (myself included)).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: In English, it's an idiom commonly used to mean "I think that you are protesting _so much_ about this that you secretly harbour the qualities derided in the original statement." e.g. "You went to see Infinity War without me, didn't you?" "No! Of course not! I would never do that! Don't be so stupid! How dare you! Grrr! Argh!" "Methinks you doth protest too much", i.e. "it looks like you're lying because of your overreaction". This is why good advice to lie properly is to do so quickly and quietly ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, you've just persuaded me that I should probably read Shakespeare...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: I honestly don't know whether the idiom has anything to do with Shakespeare. It may. It may not ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "The lady doth protest too much methinks" is from Hamlet

Comment: @DaveCousineau: I know where the words are from, but I am saying that I am not qualified to confirm to Andrey that the full meaning of the contemporary English idiom may be ascribed to that work. (But it probably does.)

Comment: This post is proof of the original assertion.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Saying you cannot analyze/quantify/measure feelings disqualifies an entire science whose measurements involve large censuses of questions like "How do you feel about...?" (not only but also) - it's called sociology, and perhaps surprising to some, there are falsifiable claims done in the field, not to mention ongoing quantitative research. In fact, as @MSalters mentions, they have some of the most rigorous and well documented methodology of all the sciences (and I second this with impunity).

**Word of caution** - the following is an attempt by me to generate a metric. **I am by no means an expert** in the field, and it may be rubbish. If we have users who have a more technical understanding of modern research methods, I would appreciate comments about them/links/even edits. If any good reference is given I will try and find the time to read it and summarize how it can be applied here.

One option for a quantitative method, which may or may not be agreed to by everyone is this:

1. Measure over a given period of time what percent of new comers of any given "grouping" manages to get to some agreed upon score, say 500, to define users who managed to become a part of SO society.
2. Compare this with the same for the global population.
3. Ask any user who have not made it to said score why do they not participate more. If they answer the feel unwelcome (and only in this case), follow up with, what do you feel the reasons are?

Of course, the next step is also controversial, but can still be done - I'm talking about analysis:

1. If the percent of thick eye-brow people who do not make it to 500 is the same as that as that of the global population, consider SO in general unbiased against thick eye-brow people, otherwise biased.
2. If a large percent (say 20%) of "failed" (in the sense described above) of thick eye-brow say they did not manage to join the community due to there uniqueness:

   a. If SO was deemed unbiased:

   - Go over all interactions manually, and see if there are users who can be attributed this behavior, and act with a heavy hand.
   - Consider this a cultural thing that may not be beaten without extensive education on SO expectation of new users. If someone was shamed for their eyebrows for their entire lives, they are bound to see such shaming everywhere, unless we all know how to be extremely gentle.

   b. If SO was deemed biased - this is a failure of SO as a society, and only drastic measures may be able to save it.

All definition can are subject to change, but only prior to the experiment. In any case, I do not see a real problem with analyzing feelings, and drawing conclusions from them.

Disclaimer: I have thick eye-brows, so I can use that as an example.

**Second thought** - perhaps it is better to ask **all** subjects of group (regardless of failure) if they feel discriminated against as a better measure. I'm not sure.

**Caveats from comments**

- @jpmc26 linked to an awesome video: https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8?t=18m4s. To quote Thomas Sowell . from said movie:

> What is amazing to me, is that this notion, that people would be evenly represented, except for these institutional policies, **that notion has such momentum behind it, without a spec of evidence being asked or presented**.

so defining bias as above may be completely misguided.

Comment: Good point with sociology. I cannot immediately comment on the proposed quantitative method, but it is immediately obvious that there is *some* scientific method behind it, whereas in the blog post I understood only *"throw away all the magnifying glasses, someone on Twitter screeches 'Racists! Racists!', therefore it must be true"*-which did not look like a scientific method at all. (+1)

Comment: I have studied both physics and political science (odd combination, I know). The political science dept. was much, _much_ stricter about proper documentation. Sociology often has the same emphasis, and with good reason. Precisely because the subject is so fuzzy do you require a sharply defined methodology. I feel it's unfair to taint the reputation of sociology as a science by linking it to this particular blog post, which utterly fails to document methodology.

Comment: Sociology is also how you might analyze the effects of any changes that are made, instead of just measuring progress by "things feel better, I guess."  Note that I do like the blog idea of adding a question building wizard to help new posters.

Comment: I'd upvote this ten times if I could. For some reason people seem to miss the point _any_ metric is better than _no_ metric, and proceeds to _guess_ at problems because they have no metrics

Comment: @MSalters You would be surprised how many physicists migrate toward the social sciences. Anyway - I meant Sociology as an answer to the abhorrent lack of analysis of said blog. This is a post to empower the field as the correct scientific paradigm for the question, not to taint it! You comment rattled me enough to warrant an edit - **How do I make it clear Sociology is the proven and valid way to separate that blog mess of accusations and facts?** - In no way do I want the field marred at all.

Comment: @MSalters Also - is the wording in the first paragraph OK? It was a bit of a snide remark (not nice I know), as I found it annoying it was reiterated in some responses to the blog "there should be no analysis", where in fact, there is a very accurate way to do analysis if one wants too.

Comment: *"I meant Sociology as an answer to the abhorrent lack of analysis of said blog"* - Accepted this as answer. This is roughly what I would like to see in blog posts that deal with such serious issues like racism or more generally, unjust discrimination. I don't think that the blog post can actually be modified, because so many people have commented on it, but I hope that the discussion will have some influence on how such problems are approached in the future. It's no longer linked on the main page anyway, and I did not demand that the blog post is fixed within some time frame => "solved" (?).

Comment: Quant and Qual are routinely used in most production grade apps.  I run the tech team at http://truthlab.com/, but a lot of other tools exist like user testing, user zoom, and even qualtrics could be used to provide a framework for making this loose art into a science.

Comment: @kabanus Off topic, but I just want to let you know that I am thick of brow as well and you are not alone in this struggle, we will prevail. Anyways here's an [article on Chinese face reading](http://brainchanger.com/chinesefacereading/) and what is said about thick eyebrows.

Comment: "If the percent of thick eye-brow people who do not make it to 500 is the same as that as that of the global population, consider SO in general unbiased against thick eye-brow people, otherwise biased." This is a non sequitur. Bias and discrimination do not automatically follow from disproportionate statistics: https://youtu.be/Y021WAdUlW8?t=18m4s, nor do disadvantages follow necessarily from discrimination. I highly recommend the entire video.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's a great video. I quoted a particular sentence around the time you link too which drives home the point (I think). Many thanks.

Comment: (Update 2018-05-04: Unaccepted again. Nothing wrong with your answer, but the people keep voting, maybe they find something else more useful... I'll just wait until it stabilizes)

Answer (score 14):

The passage you find problematic...

> When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done.

... is, *in a literal sense*, true. Feeling just are. You don't need to know of any cause, of any motivation, to recognise a feeling exists. That said, feelings do have causes and motivations. If several people (or perhaps just one person) tell you something you are doing is causing them negative feelings, you might be inclined to consider what the causes of such feelings might be, and whether there is something you can do about this situation. Perhaps there will be, perhaps there won't -- you might conclude there is nothing you can, or should, do about it. Either way, *a feeling is a signal*.

Back to the blog post, note that the body of the post never says, at any point, that this community is unwelcoming, or not inclusive, or racist, or misogynous (the title, admittedly, is "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming"; I put that down to -- perhaps misguided -- editorial expediency rather than an outright accusation). It just says that a significant number of people feel it as unwelcoming, especially people belonging to some specific groups. *This is not a rhetorical trick*, for the reasons I discussed in the previous paragraph. (Also, it is worth emphasising that second order effects are a thing: it is possible for non-discriminatory practices to affect different groups of people in different ways.)

Once Stack Overflow staff got wind of this signal, they considered what might be causing those feelings, and came to the conclusion there was an issue worth addressing. (For more on that, see the answers to blog post related questions by Tim Post -- [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color/366683#366683), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366645/please-ask-if-there-is-a-problem-before-telling-us-there-is-a-problem/366690#366690), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who/366924#366924) and Shog -- [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366645/please-ask-if-there-is-a-problem-before-telling-us-there-is-a-problem/366648#366648), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness/366785#366785)) In a similar way, from the moment the blog post went live we have been introspecting, butting heads on Meta as we consider the very same matter. Admittedly, the blog post itself does not emphasise this process of coming to a conclusion. I consider that a rhetorical choice. (Not an unreasonable one, I'd add, even though it has perhaps caused some avoidable Meta turmoil. Meta, on the other hand, is an appropriate venue for this extended, and so very meta, discussion.)

In summary, on your core question...

> Believe or investigate?

... I would say there is no dichotomy here: the belief and the investigation address different things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It says "someone **tells** you how they feel". Cannot it happen that people *lie* to you about their feelings? Can it not be that they themselves cannot clearly articulate what exactly their feelings are? As if it's not known that some people use statements about their feelings to manipulate others. As I said above, the actual causes of the feelings can be entirely different from what the feeler thinks, so you essentially can't infer anything at all from such a statement, at least not very easily.

Comment: On the dichtonomy: This seems to work only with benign Bayesian beliefs. In my question I stated the concern (hopefully I'm wrong) that it seems as if certain premises (how extraordinary sounding they might be) are assumed to be **undeniable** facts. The Bayesian beliefs can be adjusted by looking at more evidence. But the assumption of *undeniable* facts seems like a blueprint for a sect-like belief system based on undeniable expressions of feelings of some persons that are for some reason elevated to the status of the Delphi-Oracle. I hope I express my concerns clearly enough.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin On the first comment: yes, that can happen. Hypothetically, the other party might be trying to manipulate you, or utterly confused about their own feelings. That just means you have to take that into account when it comes down to reflecting about the matter. "Can't infer anything at all" is very different from "not very easily". (But back to the case at hand, you'd also need to have actual reasons to believe those who say they feel SO is unwelcoming are lying or confused about their feelings before claiming that -- otherwise you'd be falling into the same trap.)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin On the second comment: Excluding the atypical cases discussed above, the fact that an expression of feeling reveals *is the feeling itself*. The danger you identify is jumping without mediation from this fact to asserting a fact about something else. My point is that *there actually has been mediation between the claims*, even if the mediation is not all that transparently visible from reading the blog post alone.

Comment: On "transparently visible": Alright, if the blogpost would say something like: *"we've used the best magnifying glasses that we could get and came to the conclusion that those reports about negative feelings have a real reason, and this reason is the major cause of hostility on SO"*, that would be an entirely different story. But unfortunately, the blog post says "pack up your magnifying glass", which kind-of seems to imply quite the opposite.

Comment: (@AndreyTyukin Another note on "the feeling itself". With respect to the examples you give on item #1, I'd say the migraine and the rage were real. That their causes weren't what the person who felt them consciously believed at first is a separate matter. Blurring this line amounts to reductionism of a kind I don't subscribe to.)

Comment: The point I was trying to make: the rage might be real, but it had nothing to do with "incompetent colleagues". Likewise, the subjective perception of being bullied on SO might be caused not by SO itself, but by some different, entirely unrelated reason.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin On the magnifying glass: I ascribe that primarily to rhetorical framing. There is also the inescapable observation that good faith users feeling unwelcome is a problem for Stack Overflow (the company) to deal with, quite independently of what can actually be done to address it. (On a slightly pedantic note, I'd say a reason that justifies taking no action is still a "real reason": it is not fake in any sense. In your example, the "unresolved conflicts from ten years ago" are a real reason.)

Comment: Maybe it's "rhetorical framing", maybe the author just wanted to be witty and the sentence was a bit tongue-in-cheek. My problem is that after reading all the related questions for days, I seriously lost the ability to distinguish between statements that were made ironic, and statements that were made without irony. I mean: sexism? RACISM? Those are really serious issues, even if it is currently not possible to present the evidence in a convincing and comprehensible way, could one at least choose the words in the blog post more carefully, and structure the arguments more precisely?

Comment: When dealing with such issues like sexism and racism, I seriously wouldn't mind missing some witty rhetorical formulations, and would instead prefer dry lawyer-language, if this helps to make the statements more precise. I don't see at all how the blog post is precise, as I said in my question, there is an entire paragraph that seems to consist entirely out of invalid arguments and inferences. When we are talking about racism, couldn't we be a bit more precise, please? Am I somehow asking to much?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The rhetorical framing I'm talking about has to do with the primary concern of the post being acknowledging there is an issue, rather than explaining how this conclusion was reached. The post could have been clearer, indeed; people with varying views on the matter agree on that. In fact, Tim Post himself has said something to that effect in [the answer I labelled #3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366924/2751851).

Comment: I have a feeling that waking up one morning and finding that myself, and everyone else I interact with on SO, has become labeled racist/sexist overnight, is grossly insulting.  It's just a feeling, though... oh wait! It's not, I have evidence!

Comment: If we assume for a minute that there is a problem with racism/sexism on SO, how can we judge how much effort, if any, is required to mitigate it, what that effort should be, and how it would affect other problems, (because there will always be problems, and many are linked with other problems and/or with desired functionality)?

Comment: I mean, if there is upsetting instances of race/gender abuse, can they not be flagged and so handled by the mods, same as any other abusive behaviour?  Is this not happening already?  Why is that mechanism inadequate to deal with it, if/when it happens?

Comment: [1/2] @MartinJames Part of my point is that, Twitter frenzies and Meta frenzies aside, the post doesn't say everyone on SO is racist/sexist, or anything even close to that. The primary concern isn't with outright discriminatory behaviour (such as flaggable instances of racism and misogyny), but with how non-discriminatory practices might inadvertently turn out to be exclusionary. That is what I meant by "second order effects".

Comment: [2/2] @MartinJames That said, (2) "how can we judge [...]" -- that is a very broad question. It is what we, in our peculiar way, are trying to figure out through all those Meta questions, and what SO HQ is -- hopefully -- trying to do in a reasoned way. Do note that over the last few days, amidst all the confusion, there have been several constructive, actionable, well thought-out proposals that aim at addressing the identified issue in some way.

Comment: @duplode Wait a second. Second order effects? Like, for example, the effect that dark skin color is positively correlated with living in a non-English speaking country with bad education system, and therefore also positively correlated with asking bad question? Do we have to infer that Stack Overflow wants to start a worldwide campaign to teach everyone to speak English, and build hundred thousand universities in countries inhabited primarily by "people of color"? That sounds improbable. The more probable alternative seemed to be the easier one "oh, let's just blame everything on racists".

Comment: I mean, I have a feeling/worry that SO quality standards are being tied to emotive race/gender issues in order to provide a shield against anyone objecting to the overall lowering of such standards for everyone.  Since I cannot demonstrate that with any evidence, I don't ask for any mitigating changes, vote to close any meta posts I disagree with or take any other such measures  - I cannot justify them:)  If I'm right, it seems very familiar.  Bottom-feeding to increase business is what the US banks tried in 2007, and it didn't work out too well for them..

Comment: @AndreyTyukin That *is* improbable, but it is also far removed from what I have been saying here. I'm talking about things that happen within SO, not about broad societal correlations that are patently unrealistic to address here. Cf. [the first answer by Tim I linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366683/2751851).

Comment: @MartinJames I understand your worry, but at least for now I see enough sense in most of what staff has been saying to not actually feel it.

Comment: @halfer Thanks -- I felt this needed a paragraph break, but wasn't sure about where to put it :)

Comment: @MartinJames That's exactly why I find that one sentence so dangerous. If the community accepts such accusations as a given fact without seeing any evidence, then no further discussion would be necessary at all: it is then just common knowledge that everyone who disagrees with anything is a racist & misogynist, done. Would you want to hang around on a website that is generally known to consist of racists? I wouldn't want to...

Comment: "Back to the blog post, note that the post never says, at any point, that this community is unwelcoming, or not inclusive, or racist, or misogynous." Did you read the title? "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming..."

Comment: @stiemannkj1 You actually have a point... I think most of my point still stands, so I have attempted to get away with an edit.

Answer (score 14):

I have been a long time Stack Overflow user and I was equally taken aback by the blog post.

I started out at Stack Overflow when I was 14 or 15 I guess. Apart from constructive criticisms, I've not had any personal ill-feelings. No one discriminated me based on the age. Like, I don't ever remember any one commenting, "Hey kiddo, what do you know?"

In fact, Stack Overflow was the first "inclusive" community I have been part of.

Regarding the new members are being "intimidated" thing:

Stack Overflow community have not been *as* kind as they could be, when the OP doesn't follow the basic rules in "How to ask a question?"

Even in that, if by off-chance someone does get hostile,the other members of the community step up and comment in support of the OP. If I remember right, hostile members who continue their hostility are warned and even suspended, and I can think of at least one such instance where that happened right here on meta. So users being attacked aren't taken lightly over here, because the members care for each other.

Now, there are some *very* basic things that are asked to be followed for the OPs own good. I can still see many users commenting to the user along the lines:

> Please read  for how to ask a question.

Also if by intimidation, the post refers to comments like

> What have you tried?
>   gimme teh codez.com

kind of thing, then I have to disagree for this to be a form of intimidating experience. If any, it is the utter laziness on the OPs part to read the basics of a site that is if I remember right is shown multiple times when someone is new to the site.

This has been the most "welcoming" community for me and I speak for myself. I can think of a couple of ways to make the experience more "welcome"

1. A list of good and bad questions and answers could be shown to the users. After that they should be able to mark which is a good question and which is not. This simple test will give them a fair and hands-on experience of what's acceptable and what's not around here.
2. A canonical meta post could be created that addresses all the basic components of a good question and answer.

I wanted to make a similar post as Andrey but since I wasn't as active as before, I didn't want to stir the Hornet's nest. Kudos to you for raising  this.

Comment: I will interpret your story as (anecdotal) evidence that it is possible for more people from other countries to have a similar positive experience. Thank you very much for sharing this! :]

Comment: I turned 15 a few months back. Sadly, I can't relate to your first paragraph :(

Comment: @Adi219 that's sad! But with all these reforms in place, this place could only get better. Hang in there!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, people can lie.  Yes, people can get their feelings wrong.  No, you don't need to be hunting down and specifically discouraging a category of people for your actions to have a disproportionate harm to that category of people.

The state of the art in finding out how people feel about something is actually to ask them how they feel.

You can throw on extra layers of validation and trying to detect lies on top of it, and sociologists do.  (For example, sociologists study using more/less loaded language when asking if someone is racist, and the difference between in-person and phone and text based survey responses, and behavior vs claims)

If you want to understand how attitude surveys work, you might want to find a good Q&A site on sociology.

If you approach people who are potential users of stack overflow (programmers, say) and ask them "Do you feel stack overflow is welcoming?  Why don't you use stack overflow?", there is little reason to suspect they are going to be engaging in a wide-spread conspiracy to generate false attitude data.

When analyzing that data, you should include a bayesian prior of such a wide-spread conspiracy (or whatever other effect).  But **taking people at face value** is a great first approximation.

What you do to find out what people feel is you *ask them*, and when they respond you *assume they are telling the truth*, then you *check against reality* for blatant disagreements.

If you find no contraditions with reality, you keep on with the working hypothesis that they are telling the truth about their feelings.

Barring a blatant disagreement between what those people say they are feeling, and reality, that is what you work with.

Or:

> When someone tells you how they feel, you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done.

If you run into evidence of a huge conspiracy to generate lies on your survey, or other evidence, or even a credible theory why your survey is gibberish, then you pull your magnifying glass out again.  But those are not in evidence.

Comment: This is not about "conspiracies". Let's take a step back: The least that we can agree on is that the post was controversial (evidence: meta). I think that there also is a consensus that it was "poorly worded" (in several ways). But not only that: It was precluding a discussion. Technically by disabling comments. More importantly: By basically denying others the right to question the statements that have been made (which contradicts the philosophy of SO - at least, as I perceived it until now). This request points out the most critical flaws in this regard, in a clean and objective manner.

Comment: @Marco13 I would not describe the OP's text as "clean": that OP is a *mess* I'd downvote just for poor formatting and incoherence.  I mean, inline **EDIT**, repeated reference to a offending "paragraph" that goes on for paragraphs before you see it, let alone the argument structure itself (more like a pile of twigs than a building).  "Objective" is less ridiculous, but still something I'd disagree with; it reads like a screed by someone who is quite offended by something, not an objective analysis of a poorly worded 2 sentences of a blog post.  I could be wrong, I didn't ask the OP.

Comment: This gets at the heart of what I tried to say with my answer in a much more direct way.

Comment: @Yakk. I agree, some formulations are probably sub-optimal, and the question has grown somewhat iteratively out of the discussion in the comments. I've prepared a much more compressed shorter version, but I don't know whether it would be fair now to swap out the question, because quite a few people have already voted on it, and I don't want to simply replace it by something they haven't voted on. I'm obviously not well-versed in such discussions. I understand why your downvoted, and I thank you for feedback.

Comment: One could probably have written it more compactly, but the topic is difficult, and the request for updating a blog post (which is unprecedented, AFAICT) *has* to lay out a line of argumentation that is convincing, *beyond* a shallow "I'm offended by that, you should delete it". The *reasoning* behind why the poor wording is critical should become clear. So if you think that what was written in the blog is OK, then keep the downvote. If you think that the blog post should be updated, then upvote. (And you can also suggest improvements/edits for the formatting, for that matter)

Comment: @Marco13 "But not only that: It was precluding a discussion. Technically by disabling comments." -- That hasn't precluded discussion, as demonstrated by there being loads and loads of Meta questions about the post, many of them with active and open-minded participation of SO staff. Comments were disabled on the blog post because they would have been a nightmare to moderate, especially on a post also meant to be read by people outside the community.

Comment: @duplode One could ask why they knew that it would have been a "nightmare to moderate", or how the post would have to be worded in order to *prevent* this nightmare, but I could only give somewhat cynical answers to that. But the important thing is: **This** request is not about the technical part, but about the fact that counterarguments have been wiped away proactively, by saying ~"It's true, because ... feelings". Again: **This** request aims at improving the wording of the blog post, and explains in detail why this is important.

Comment: @Marco13 [This answer by Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366690/2751851) explicitly addresses the issue of comments.

Comment: @Marco13 I'm aware that people are unable to read what that blog post said.  Reading comprehension failures are common when emotions get high.  The blog post didn't say "It's true, because ... feelings" it said "The feelings exist."  It states so explicitly.  The amount of quite frankly **coddling** you are asking for is ironic as is my rough response to your request that your feelings being respected.  This comment, by the way, is the kind of comment and behavior that the post says makes people feel unwelcome.

Comment: @Yakk The ~"feelings" part in the comment above was intended to emphasize what this request referred to, without fully quoting the blog post and the OP again, which laid the issue out in a detail that I consider adequate (although others might disagree). However, the discussion is indeed a bit heated in some places, and I'll have to see whether it cooled down a bit until tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure that anyone is saying there's a mass conspiracy. The way I read it, the issue is more about the logical leap from "we've talked to members of minority groups and some of them say they feel unwelcome" to "our community has a problem". This implies that we as a community are generally not welcoming to minority groups. If this implication is purposeful, then we need more information in the form of evidence in order to understand how to fix the problem. If it's accidental, the blog post is worded poorly and should be clarified.

Answer (score 6):

@AndreyTyukin from your name, I can tell that you are a male, likely white and from Russia. From my name, I'm sure you can guess something about "my sex, gender, race, ethnicity, or nationality". "Never in my entire life has this community asked me any" of those questions, and yet I ***do not*** come to the same conclusion that "therefore, my experience is that this community is not just inclusive" but exerts a strong attractive force.

Your comments all remain respectful and genuinely curious, and thank you for that. I would ask you though, to re-examine your own argument and consider how personal experiences with this community may lead any individual to believe undeniable facts (about inclusiveness, for example), about a community.

One personal example about my experiences: I was told yesterday "You are wrong, learn more about [product X]", about a product I build. I don't know if I would have gotten the same comment if my name revealed something different or nothing about my "sex, gender, race, ethnicity, or nationality," but there are [psychological studies](http://gender.stanford.edu/news/2014/why-does-john-get-stem-job-rather-jennifer) that lead me to believe that perhaps there would be a difference in experience.

I benefit greatly from this community and am not saying that small comments like the one above will discourage me from participating. However, as the blog post begins with, I believe there is room for improvement in this community.

Comment: Could you share a link to this comment?

Comment: I was also baffled by this conclusion, among others.

Comment: @LutzHorn For me, this looks like the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069990/test-brokered-message/50071238#comment87163251_50071238) was caused by something like a typo, but I'm not sure. However, I'm pretty sure that 1. a "Mario Hoeger" may have received a similar comment, 2. English is a second language for the commenter, 3. The commenter is a newbie himself. In any case: The problem of drawing conclusions from *individual* experiences is obvious, but in this request, it was only made as part of the (subjective) Motivation, which does not affect the core of the request.

Comment: @MarieHoeger You are mostly right with your guesses, and I admit that the process probably wouldn't work as well in some other countries, especially for people who don't have access to the internet. That's why I talked about the broader community and some older now-obsolete forums: before there was Stack Overflow, I hung around on programming forums with a nickname that looked like a hexadecimal number, and still had no problems whatsoever, nobody ever asked me where I'm from, who I am, and what I want there.

Comment: @MarieHoeger My general line of argument was rather about the general observation that those people flooded the entire planet with the most awesome tools and ideas, without asking anything in exchange. If this is not generosity, then I don't know what is. Then they've built all those on-line platforms like Stack Overflow, and invited everyone in. Just look at the page of top users: India, US, Sri Lanka, Half-Europe, Armenia, Singapore, China, Israel, Tunisia, Trinidad and Tobago... (no Russia, hm, well...). This is not welcoming, seriously?

Comment: I don't say that it is perfect. I truly believe that it can be made more welcoming. Indeed, the reason why I clicked on the blog post in the first place was that I hoped to get some hints how to deal with less cooperative users in a more friendly and non-confrontational way. But instead it seemed to me that unsupported claims of racism / sexism are used to preclude any discussion. I see that there might be problems with sexism and people using greetings and pronouns not appropriate for the gender of the users they address. But I don't want that it is used as a thought-terminating cliché.

Comment: What makes you think that comment was because of your gender? It seems very generic.

Comment: @nvoigt Maybe Marie knows enough about her own experiences to be able to make an educated guess? She doesn't even say the comment was definitely because of her gender, but merely that "perhaps there would be a difference in experience".

Comment: @duplode My experience is that there are enough generalist people that are "wrong on the internet" to explain the comment. Assuming that it was a "specialized" person being "wrong on the internet" that targets people based on gender seems unsubstantiated. So I asked her to share what made her think it was based on gender. If it was an educated guess, educate me.

Comment: @nvoigt This is **not** referring to the specific case that involved Marie Hoeger (!), but my impression is that there is a strong (and increasing) tendency to apply double standards: When a man is rude towards a man, he does so because he is rude. When a man is rude towards a woman, he does so because he is sexist. One of the main issues that I had with the blog post was exactly along these lines: There is a problem, and people instinctively seem to call "sexism, racism". What's wrong with this implication was pointed out in this request, and the blog post should therefore be reworded.

Comment: What is the relevance of Andrei's race and gender, Marie? Why do you bring that up? Why do you attach his whiteness and maleness to your reasoning?

Comment: _"there are psychological studies that lead me to believe that perhaps there would be a difference in experience"_ I don't see why. Absolutely nothing in what you were told has anything to do with gender or race, and white males are told the exact same thing on SO _all the time_.

Comment: I am female, and I have to say that I wouldn't assume a comment like that to be posted more freely because of my gender. I used to use my real name here, until I switched to a neutral nickname to see if I would notice different behavior from other users. No difference noted. Some comments are just terse or even rude, don't take them personally. (This is anecdotal evidence, of course, maybe I was just lucky.)

Comment: Besides, Marie, this was the best opportunity for a tounge-in-cheek answer stating that you agree, you always feel the need to learn more about the product you actually develop. And it would have turned the comment absolutely around, the guy (or whatever) probably expressing joy that the help came from the absolute authority on the subject.

Comment: -- I agree that there was absolutely nothing sexist os racist about that comment. And I keep wondering just what people mean when they say racism in SO in the first place. Do you know what color I have? How do you know that? There are problems in the world but there is definitely no need to create some where there isn't any.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome interesting to notice that proposing to learn more about a product one build rather strongly suggests that commenter didn't pay any attention at all to any of the personal details (like they didn't even bother to check the user profile etc). Whether their comment was technically correct or wrong is not really relevant in this context, what is relevant is that commenter appears to be focusing exclusively on the text of the post and totally ignoring poster's personal details (professional, gender and whatever else one could find about post author if they were interested)

Comment: I think this answer highlights the issue that I've seen on IPS: a person feels that they *may* have been treated differently due to being in a minority group.  They post about it in as neutral a way as they can.  A bunch of people who *are not members of that minority group* then rush in to tell the OP why they are **wrong**, frequently in a condescending manner.  Note that I'm not referring to Modus' comment, which, even if she didn't identify herself as a female, is merely saying "that's not the experience I've had", rather than "here's why you're wrong!".

Comment: @gnat - I think I agree with what you are saying, if you are that the comment had nothing to do with any personal metadata about the OP.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome yes, that's exactly my point, it looks like the comment had nothing to do with any personal metadata about the OP

Comment: @Beofett - so you are saving that *You are not paranoid if everyone really is out to get you!*, got it!

Comment: @feelingunwelcome Oh, so I guess I should respond to your strawman by saying "so by putting words in my mouth, you're saying *saying minority groups may feel like they're treated differently makes me feel guilty, so I get really defensive and try to change the topic!*.  Got it!"

Comment: @Beofett - that is just as equally a logical fallacy *Circular Reasoning*, too bad you missed the sarcasm. The point I and others are making is clear, *If you look to be offended, you will find it in everything* and that this particular case they presented empirically has absolutely nothing in it to imply sexism. So, I stand by my statement, *If you are looking for ????, you will see it in everything.* Just replace ???? with your favorite offense. *Feeling* that you are being treated differently is **not** the same as actually being treated differently.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome Yes, I responded to your logical fallacy with a logical fallacy.  Not sure how you could have missed the sarcasm, which I thought was pretty obvious.  Accusing me of missing the sarcasm is "one of the worst kinds of hypocrisy".  I stand by my statement: *if you are so intent on telling people who feel like they **may** be being mistreated how **wrong** they are, then you're changing **may** to **are***.

Comment: In other words, when someone says "*I don't know* if I would have gotten the same comment if my name revealed something different", and you respond by calling them a hypocrite, *it doesn't matter* if they were being treated differently for being ???, because *you're being rude, hostile, and unwelcoming **now***.

Comment: if the truth is rude, then it is just what it is. Assigning malicious intent when no reasonable person would say any exists, is pretty hypocritical in this case. Would she have claimed *Sexism* if the commenters name was `user34829349` or `Betty Codebetter`? Probably not as it is admitted she judged his intent based on his name.  That is the definition of hypocrisy, doing what you are accusing someone else of, especially when there is no evidence of them doing it. I stand by that objective assessment.

Comment: Your use of the word "truth" seems to mean "I'm going to selectively read, and put words in other people's mouths, so that I can justify my own moral outrage".  But go on using the word "hypocritical".  It's not at all ironic, I assure you!  Btw, "objective" doesn't mean what you think it does, either.

Comment: @gnat: I don't wholly disagree with your point, but it's worth considering that checking whether someone wrote a library takes a good deal more engagement than noticing whether they are male or female.

Answer (score 4):

Addressing your points:

1. If you want more details regarding how they reached the conclusion they reached, or which data they used, fair enough.

   But that's not what you're asking for. All I'm reading here is that you want them to add some footnotes or sacrifice the simplicity of the current phrasing, just to be "technically correct", which seems completely unnecessary considering that it's a blog post, not a scientific article or textbook (not saying it's fine if a blog post is wrong, but your problem appears to be that they didn't add a footnote saying "well, they can lie and so on and so forth, but ..." to justify it).

   Yes, you shouldn't always take what someone says they're feeling at face value, but if a significant number of people says they're feeling the same feelings, it's likely that's indeed what they're feeling.

   Or maybe we can just replace "They’re just what the feeler is telling you" with "They’re just what the feeler is feeling" to make it technically correct. Or you can assume a broader definition of "tell".
2. Firstly,

   > a lot of devs feel like Stack Overflow is an intimidating, unwelcoming place

   does **directly** imply

   > we really have a problem

   **if** the goal is for Stack Overflow to be a welcoming and not intimidating place.

   Secondly, an equally valid conclusion for your argument would be that both gcc and Stack Overflow are too intimidating and not welcoming enough *in general*, instead of that we're not discriminating.

   Either way, the point is that people don't feel welcome and we should do something about it.

   Note that the post only mentions that women and people of color felt unwelcome and mentions **bias** (I don't see it explicitly mentioning racism or sexism). Bias can take many forms - it might mean that we're making assumptions about women or people of other races which leads to us treating everyone how **we** want to be treated (or how we think they want to be treated) instead of hearing how **they** actually want to be treated (and changing how we treat everyone based on that).
3. All I'm reading in that quote, apart from what was addressed in the first point, is:

   > If you want to know how users feel, their feelings would be the answer.

   Which is `A implies A` - something which is obviously true.

   Although knowing *why* users feel the way they do tends to be the more important part, but that's somewhat beside the point.

Comment: 1. I don't insist that everything the blog says has to be completely waterproof and 100% documented in the sense of [MSalters comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366954/request-edit-clarify-the-stack-overflow-isn-t-very-welcoming-blog-post/367152#comment582734_366972) comment. But I don't want that analysis of complex problems is replaced by slogans that seem like they are borrowed from heated political debates on Twitter, and that those slogans are stated in a manner as if they were undeniable self-evident facts.

Comment: 2. I did NOT conclude that "Stack Overflow is not racist and sexist". 
That's exactly what the remark in my posting is about. 
To quote myself: "There is no proof that people from certain minority groups are not treated differently.". 
If the structure of the argument is invalid, it does not prove that the conclusion is necessarily false. The problem is that by an invalid argument, anything can be "proven", it does not prove or disprove anything, so that's just not helpful.

Comment: 3. Well, yes. If you extract & separate this statement from the context that "SO is not welcoming" and "Yes, we really have a problem", and if you additionally do not interpret anything into what the users feel, and do not try to use it as argument to push some policy changes, then this statement indeed becomes just a truism. But then I don't understand why it is in the blog in the first place. When serious topics like racism are discussed, I expect to see some clear arguments and evidence, not a wall of hypnotic suggestions consisting of emotions, tautologies, truisms, and rhetoric tricks.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin 2. I didn't express myself well there. I rewrote most of that.

Answer (score -2):

One thing which I think hasn't been addressed *enough* in answers is the fact that Stack Overflow is a huge community, and that like almost any huge community, it's far from homogeneous. It's important to keep this in mind when interpreting any statements made about the community.

For example, we can say that New York City is a wealthy city. It's easy to come up with many metrics which support this statement, and very hard to find anyone (whether a scientist or a lay person) who would argue that the statement is false.

But it's a big city. You can go to parts of the city where people are very poor and conditions are dirty and unsafe. There are tens of thousands of people in the city who are homeless. They probably make up less than 1% of the city's population, but it's a big enough absolute number that it's also not wrong to say "New York City has a homeless problem". Over 90% of the towns in the United States have fewer residents than New York City has homeless people.

[Sources for the above: [1](https://patch.com/new-york/new-york-city/nyc-homeless-population-grew-4-year-data-show), [2](https://www.bowery.org/homelessness/), [3](http://www.coalitionforthehomeless.org/basic-facts-about-homelessness-new-york-city/), [4](https://www.statista.com/statistics/241695/number-of-us-cities-towns-villages-by-population-size/), plus my own experiences in various parts of the city.]

So imagine, you can have a whole town's worth of homeless people within one "wealthy community". Is it so hard to understand the concept that Stack Overflow, while teeming with helpful, generous, and yes, *welcoming* people, **also** is a community which suffers from being hostile and elitist?

Comment: Well, yes... If you say "NY has a homeless problem", a person with some common knowledge might believe it without requesting further evidence. But if vast majority of New York's homeless would wear special rain-proof costumes that look like white cubes decorated by monochrome geometric patterns, and you would state that "NY has a homeless problem, especially many women and people of color are forced to live on the street" (in bold face, repeatedly), I would ask you whether you've actually checked who's inside the cubical costumes.

Comment: I don't want to assume you're attacking my answer, but if you are, I would point out that I purposely kept my answer focused on the blog post's title statement because I felt it was the larger and more central point. Many people are challenging the notion that SO is even unwelcoming at all. Someone who doesn't believe that SO is unwelcoming *at all* won't even get to the issue of whether it is *especially* unwelcoming toward women or people of color.

Comment: Nothing here is about "attacking". However, many seem (to some extent) agree that SO is not "welcoming", with the caveat that the interpretations of this vague word, and possible reasons, are currently being discussed. And in this regard, people would probably not have criticized the title or the "welcoming" part of the blog post. What people **did** criticize is the conflation of newbies+women+color, and the fact that *the whole SO community* was "implicitly accused of having an implicit bias". I wonder how one could argue that the post was *not* (at the very least!) poorly worded.

Comment: @Marco13 On "implicitly accused of having an implicit bias": The blog post seems to put so much emphasis on the "women-and-POC"-part, that it seems as if it's a much larger problem than sarcasm and snarky comments caused by bad questions. Given that there is a significant problem with sarcasm and snarky comments, and if we assume that the blog post accurately represents the proportions between the subproblems, then it would mean that all of SO is completely racist & sexist.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It's hard to tell what the purpose and intention of the post should have been. The fact that there hasn't at least been a clarifying statement by the management makes it worse. So the door is left open for speculations like the following: This [tweet and the post that it refers to](https://mobile.twitter.com/JayHanlon/status/989589926458032128) let me assume that someone felt the necessity to stir together some slimy mix of compassion and social justice, to show the world what a great, caring person he is. (Jay: Feel free to concur and explain *why you posted it in this form*)